# Python: Removing list element while iterating over list

Tags: python, list

I'm iterating over a list of elements in Python, do some action on it, and then remove them if they meet certain criteria.

```
for element in somelist:
    do_action(element)
    if check(element):
        remove_element_from_list
```

What should I use in place of remove_element?
I have seen similar questions asked, but notice the presence of the do_action part that is to be executed for all elements and thus eliminates the solution of using filters.

Comment: Can't you split it in two steps i.e. for all elements do the action, then remove elements ?

Comment: You should **NEVER** delete an element from a list while iterating over it in a for loop. You could use a while loop instead. Or, record the indices of all the elements you want to remove and then delete them after the iteration is complete

Comment: For all: I need to modify the list in place, no copies. Actually the list is passed to a function and the list needs to be modified by that function.

Comment: @Scrontch, it's still possible (and better) to loop through the list and then **replace it's contents** as a second pass . That is why I use `[:]` in my answer

Comment: @inspectorG4dget: Your first sentence is untenable -- see my answer.

Comment: @John: @Scrontch wanted to do the deletion in a for loop, which is an inarguably bad idea.. In your example, you used a while loop, which is something that I had suggested in my comment for the exact way in which you are using your while loop.

Comment: @Scrontch:  I you haven't accepted an answer yet.  I you would, either critique the answers or accept one.  It will help those who have posted answers and it will make it more likely for you to get answers in the future.

Answer (score 211, accepted):

You could always iterate over a copy of the list, leaving you free to modify the original:

```
for item in list(somelist):
  ...
  somelist.remove(item)
```

Comment: @Scrontch Given you additional criteria of "modify the list in place", this looks like the cleanest solution.  As some have mentioned, you don't want to iterate over the same list you're modifying.

Comment: Ok, but it seems not to be performing well at all. Won't this be O(n^2)? (And that is not counting the initial list copy). Removing the element on the fly would be O(n).

Comment: Scrontch - the only performance hit is from copying the list, you're still removing the element 'on the fly' - the inner code references `somelist` which is the original list.

Comment: using map (or list comprehensions) for side effects and throwing away the result is not very pythonic

Comment: @Scrontch, O(n^2)+O(n) is still O(n^2). `list.remove()` is O(n) and it is in the loop, so removing in the loop _is_ O(n). This is one reason why 2 passes are better, they can easily both be O(n), and O(n)+O(n) is of course still O(n)

Comment: -1.  For reasons noted by gnibbler, code is not pythonic and unnecessary slow.  I wouldn't have down-voted except that I feel the 4 up-votes need to be offset.  Riccardo Galli, Mark Ransom, and gnibbler have better answers and all have less votes.

Comment: The alternative implementation is wrong. You will need to reverse 'toremove' before the map function. Otherwise later indices point to wrong objects.

Comment: This seems pretty broken, `list.remove` removes the first occurrence of a value by equality, if you were trying to remove all float values from `[0,  1, 1.0, 0]` just by doing `.remove(0.0)` etc. you would end up with `[1.0, 0.0]` which is definitely **not** the result with all float removed.

Answer (score 148):

To meet these criteria: modify original list in situ, no list copies, only one pass, **works**, a traditional solution is to iterate *backwards*:

```
for i in xrange(len(somelist) - 1, -1, -1):
    element = somelist[i]
    do_action(element)
    if check(element):
        del somelist[i]
```

Bonus: Doesn't do `len(somelist)` on each iteration. Works on any version of Python (at least as far back as 1.5.2) ... s/xrange/range/ for 3.X.

Update: If you want to iterate *forwards*, it's possible, just trickier and uglier:

```
i = 0
n = len(somelist)
while i < n:
    element = somelist[i]
    do_action(element)
    if check(element):
        del somelist[i]
        n = n - 1
    else:
        i = i + 1
```

Comment: You could also use `reversed(range(len(somelist)))` to make it look a bit nicer

Comment: it is quadratic algorithm (`O(n**2)`). Here's a [linear solution if there are many elements to remove](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2794519/4279) and you don't want to use [list comprehension](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1207461/4279) for any reason.

Comment: Is this documented/defined behavior, or is it undefined behavior that happens to work (for now)?

Comment: @Maëlan: there are O(n) `del L[i]` operations. Removing an element from a middle of a Python list is O(n) therefore the whole algorithm is quadratic O(n*n).

Comment: @jfs Oh my bad, you are right of course.

Answer (score 14):

List comp:

```
results = [x for x in (do_action(element) for element in somelist) if check(element)]
```

Comment: but the OP wants to call the "check" function **after** calling do_action

Answer (score 11):

```
for element in somelist:
    do_action(element)
somelist[:] = (x for x in somelist if not check(x))
```

If you really need to do it in one pass without copying the list

```
i=0
while i < len(somelist):
    element = somelist[i] 
    do_action(element)
    if check(element):
        del somelist[i]
    else:
        i+=1
```

Comment: Also you could use a generator expression, then no temporary list is built: `somelist[:] = (x for x in somelist if not check(element))`

Comment: -1 Elementary code review says "Doesn't work".

Comment: @John, ah well the idea was there. That's what I get for writing untested code at 6:30 before my coffee

Answer (score 7):

You can still use filter, moving to an outside function the element modification (iterating just once)

```
def do_the_magic(x):
    do_action(x)
    return check(x)

# you can get a different filtered list
filter(do_the_magic,yourList)

# or have it modified in place (as suggested by Steven Rumbalski, see comment)
yourList[:] = itertools.ifilter(do_the_magic, yourList)
```

Comment: Your arguments to `filter` are in the wrong order.  Also, he wants the list modified in place, so use `itertools.ifilter` and assign to a slice:  `yourList[:] = itertools.ifilter(do_the_magic, yourList)`

Comment: thanks, fixed the order. I didn't notice the "in place" requirement

Answer (score 4):

Another way of doing so is:

```
while i<len(your_list):
    if #condition :
        del your_list[i]
    else:
        i+=1
```

So, you delete the elements side by side while checking

Answer (score 2):

You can make a generator that returns everything that isn't removed:

```
def newlist(somelist):
    for element in somelist:
        do_action(element)
        if not check(element):
            yield element
```

Comment: Except the OP want the list modified in place, presumably there are other references to it, so creating a filtered copy doesn't solve the whole problem.

Comment: @Paul, it's a little unfair to judge by criteria that weren't part of the original question. The hard requirement to do the update in-place came in a comment after I gave this answer.

Comment: true, I see this all the time with the parsing questions. There is a process of discovery, since the original question usually leaves out 1 or 12 (or 12!) vital bits of information.

Comment: To make this in-place assign to a slice:  `somelist[:] = (x for x in newlist(someList))`

Answer (score 0):

Why not rewrite it to be

```
for element in somelist: 
   do_action(element)  

if check(element): 
    remove_element_from_list
```

See this question for how to remove from the list, though it looks like you've already seen that
[Remove items from a list while iterating](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1207406/remove-items-from-a-list-while-iterating-in-python)

Another option is to do this if you really want to keep this the same

```
newlist = [] 
for element in somelist: 
   do_action(element)  

   if not check(element): 
      newlst.append(element)
```

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly in-place, but some idea to do it:

```
a = ['a', 'b']

def inplace(a):
    c = []
    while len(a) > 0:
        e = a.pop(0)
        if e == 'b':
            c.append(e)
    a.extend(c)
```

You can extend the function to call you filter in the condition.