# Python items from list to other list: weird results

Tags: python, list, append

I'm trying to transfer items from one list to the other (like below) but the result is really puzzling. Does anyone have an idea what's going on here??

```
l1=range(1,11)
l2=[]
for i in l1:
    if i>=6:
        l2.append(i)
        l1.remove(i)
print l1
print l2

l1 = [1-5, 7, 9] # and
l2 = [6, 8, 10]  # !!
```

Comment: @minitech: this sounds sarcastic.  Just because something is clear to you, it isn't clear to everyone.

Comment: @NedBatchelder: It's not, I'm actually wondering what the expected result was. Just because it's sometimes possible to figure out the intention of the code based on the general tone doesn't mean it's necessarily the right one, and I don't want to waste time answering the wrong question.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is due to the fact that you are modifying the list that you are iterating over.

If you search on SO, you'll find a number of posts regarding this. E.g., [Modifying list while iterating](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1637807/modifying-list-while-iterating), [Python: Removing list element while iterating over list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6022764/python-removing-list-element-while-iterating-over-list), etc

Answer (score 3):

You shouldn't modify a list that you're iterating or you'll get weird results. It's like cutting the branch that you're sitting on. How about creating two lists based on `l1` ?

```
big = [x for x in l1 if x >= 6]
small = [x for x in l1 if x < 6]
```

Better yet, if you care about performance:

```
big = []
small = []

for item in l1:
    if item >= 6:
        big.append(item)
    else:
        small.append(item)
```

Comment: Even better: `big = range(6, 11)` and `small = range(1, 6)` ;)

Comment: Guys, thank you all very much for your help!! I was completely unaware that I'm not allowed to edit lists over which I'm iterating. I'll just go with two lists then, no problem!