# Filtering list of dictionaries by regex match

Tags: python, python-2.7, list-comprehension

I'm writing a python script which collects metrics and I have:

- `collected`, a list containing all messages, stored as dictionaries
- `denied_metrics`, a list containing all compiled regular expressions

I want to be able to inhibit the forwarding of those messages in which `collected[i]['service']` matches at least one regular expression in `denied_metrics`.

I was trying to achieve my goal using **list comprehension** and `filter`, but I didn't manage to do that way.

### actual solution

Given that messages have the following structure:

```
msg = { 
  'service': 'foo', 
  'metric':    1.0,
  'denied':  False 
}
```

actually I'm filtering all `collected` messages like follows

```
def filter_denied( denied_metrics, collected ):
  for pattern in denied_metrics:
    for msg in collected
      if pattern.match( msg['service'] ):
        msg['denied'] = True

return [ msg for msg in collected if msg['denied'] is not True ]
```

### question

Is there a (better?) way to obtain a list of **allowed messages** using just a combination of **list comprehension** and `filter` or `reduce`?

---

#### EDIT

I was not aware about the possibility to approach the problem like @eyquem suggested by in his answer.

Comment: _"in Python it's not possible to erase collected[i] if it matches while I'm iterating on collected"_ For what reason ?

Comment: @eyquem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6022764/python-removing-list-element-while-iterating-over-list and read the 2nd comment

Comment: I wanted to be sure. See my answer please

Comment: You should read not only the second comment but all the thread, and you would see the John Machin's answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC, I might do do something like

```
allowed = [msg for msg in collected 
           if not any( dm.search(msg['service']) 
                       for dm in denied_metrics) ]
```

For example:

```
>>> pprint.pprint(collected)
[{'denied': False, 'metric': 1.0, 'service': 'ab'},
 {'denied': False, 'metric': 1.0, 'service': 'bc'},
 {'denied': False, 'metric': 1.0, 'service': 'ca'},
 {'denied': False, 'metric': 1.0, 'service': 'cb'},
 {'denied': False, 'metric': 1.0, 'service': 'bc'}]
>>> denied_metrics = [re.compile("a"), re.compile("c$")]
>>> allowed = [msg for msg in collected 
               if not any(dm.search(msg['service'])
               for dm in denied_metrics)]
>>> allowed
[{'metric': 1.0, 'service': 'cb', 'denied': False}]
```

Whether you want `search` or `match` depends upon your regexes, of course.  [BTW, wouldn't 'denied_services' be a better name?]

Comment: awesome. In the real scenario the terminology is slightly different. Thank you anyway.

Answer (score 1):

You have an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Here are two ways to delete elments of a list while iterating in it:

```
li = ['a',12,45,'h',56,'ju',0]
print li
for i in xrange(len(li)-1,-1,-1):
    if isinstance(li[i],int):
        del li[i]
print li
# prints ['a', 'h', 'ju']
```

.

```
li = ['a',12,45,'h',56,'ju',0]
L = len(li)
for i,x in enumerate(reversed(li),1):
    if isinstance(x,str):
        del li[L-i]
print li
# prints [12, 45, 56, 0]
```

In the last code `reversed()` returns an iterator, no new list has to be created.

Comment: I don't think it's an XY problem. I explicitely asked for a solution using list comprehension and/or filter, and I got it. Though, it's true that I didn't pay attention to other approaches, so I thank you for your useful answer.

Comment: I thought that you opted to use a list comprehension (attempted solution Y) because you was thinking you can't iterate-delete in a list (real X problem). But if your really first need is to find a list comp., you are right, there's no XY problem