# Remove items from two lists if they meet a criteria

Tags: python, list, time-complexity

I have two lists in python, they contain points, and I want to remove from BOTH lists any permutation that exists in both lists.

I tried writing the followiing code that fails:

```
  for indexA, pointA in enumerate(listA):
    for indexB, pointB in enumerate(listB):
       if isPermutation(listA[indexA],listB[indexB]):
            del listA[indexA]
            del listB[indexB]
```

This of course would not work because the `del` command creates a new list and the for loop will loose the reference to both lists (not to mention it takes O(n) to remove from a list in python).
There are various ways to do this when you have one list [which are mentioned here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6022764/python-removing-list-element-while-iterating-over-list). But they don't seem to be helpful when working with two lists with the dependency above.

Could anyone supply code/a way to do this? 

I care about speed.
Note: Building the list using .append() is really slow due to the fact its [amortized](http://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity).

Comment: Do you need the keep the order? If you don't, you should use sets instead of lists, compute the intersection and subtract from both.

Comment: I don't mind changing the current order, but I need the final order preserved. That is, you can sort it, but you must keep it sorted in the same way.

Comment: Can you just avoid this problem completely by *not* inserting items into listA if they are already in listB (and delete from listB at the same time), and vice-versa?  And if you actually need to maintain a list of duplicate items then have a 3rd list (ListAB) containing each item that would otherwise be in *both* listA and listB.

Comment: @jarmod No I can't. I am not the one inserting them. They are actually parsed from a different part of the program. I will note they are parsed FAST. Really fast, I am not sure how to be honest. [Its part of the blender source code](https://svn.blender.org/svnroot/bf-extensions/trunk/py/scripts/addons/io_mesh_stl/stl_utils.py), so its not magic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest first to create another list containing the elements to be deleted from the initial lists, say `listC` and then use list comprehension to modify both `listA` and `listB`.
For instance, after having obtained listC:

```
listA = [a for a in listA if a not in listC]
listB = [a for a in listB if a not in listC]
```

Comment: Is there a way to do this without using `.append()`?

Comment: @GuySoft, to which `.append()` are you referring to?

Comment: in order to create the list containing the elements to be deleted from both listA and listB you need to build the list somehow. [Here is my current code](http://pastebin.com/6tGrJSuj). . It works, but would prefer to make it faster by dropping the `.append()` on lines 13 and 14:

Comment: @GuySoft, I see. If you prefer, you could use list comprehension to create those list too. For instance, using the same code you used in the question, you could do something like `removeA = [a for a in listA for b in listB if isPermutation(a,b)]`

Comment: Thanks! Will try that and update, running out of input files to test it.

Comment: @GuySoft. You can speed up the process if your initial lists do not contain duplicate elements. In this case you can create the final list as following: `listA = [a for a in listA for b in listB if not isPermutation(a,b)]`. In this case you will have duplicate elements, but you can delete the duplicates transforming the list in a set (and then transforming to a list again if you really need lists): `listA = set(listA)`

Answer (score 0):

instead of doing it the way markusian say, you could make new listA and listB directly instead of making a listC to compare and there isn't really a need for enumerate is there?

removing the enumerate cause it isn't really needed cause it in a loop will speed it up a little.

```
listC = []
listD = []
for pointA in listA:
  for pointB in listB:
     if not isPermutation(pointA,pointB):
       listC.append(pointA)
       listD.append(pointB)
     else:
       # fix B to look like A in new listA (listC) and listB (listD)
       listC.append(pointB)
       listD.append(pointB)
```

then if you want, you could just replace the old list with the new

```
listA = listC
listB = listD
```

edit1: if you really must avoid append, you could do it this way, although, it slower on small list, not so sure about big list:

```
listC = []
listD = []
for pointA in listA:
  for pointB in listB:
     if not isPermutation(pointA,pointB):
       # a += b is like a = a + b
       listC += [pointA]
       listD += [pointB]
     else:
       # fix B to look like A in new listA (listC) and listB (listD)
       listC += [pointB]
       listD += [pointB]
```

Comment: I am trying to avoid `.append` because use its [amortized](http://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity).

Comment: if you must avoid .append, you could turn the point into a list and join it together with the list, but it slower than .append...

Comment: No point of using something slower. The point is finding something that is faster. I thought that was obvious :-/

Comment: I am trying to avoid .append because use its amortized. – GuySoft 10 hours ago, so i give you something other than append lol