# generating a regex for path

Tags: python, regex, path

I'm trying to write a function that delete unwanted paths  from a list of paths, those unwanted ones have the same pattern for example c:/project1/main/Node/Accept/*something
this is my code

```
def filtre(list):
    for i,item in enumerate(list):
        matchObject=re.search(r"(Accept/.*[/])", item) or re.search(r"(Integrate/.*[/])", item)
        if matchObject :
            list.remove(item)   
        else:
            i=i+1
    return list
```

and this an example of my global list:(Input)

```
c:/project1/main/Node/Accept/testCase1/Browse.c
c:/project1/main/Node/Accept/testCase2/navigate.c
c:/project1/main/Node/Accept/testCase2/save.c
c:/project1/main/Node/Accept/testCase4/search.c
c:/project1/main/Node/Accept
c:/project1/main/Node/Integrate
c:/project1/main/Node/Accept/destroy/fullCoverage/remove.py
c:/project1/main/Tree/Integrate/testCase1/Browse.c
c:/project1/main/Tree/Integrate
```

desired output:

```
c:/project1/main/Node/Accept
c:/project1/main/Node/Integrate
c:/project1/main/Tree/Integrate
```

I hope that is clear ,remove every path followed by more child nodes after the nodes Accept and Integrate.

Comment: Why do you have a capture group in your regexp if you're not doing a replacement? And there's no need to put `[ ]` around `/`.

Comment: Please do not call local variables `list`. You mask the builtin `list()` constructor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following regex to match the desired output:

```
(^.*?\/(?:Accept|Integrate))$
```

If you want to remove the unnecessary paths.. you can use the following:

```
(^.*?\/(?:Accept|Integrate))(?!$).*
```

Python code:

```
def filtre(list):
    for i,item in enumerate(list):
        matchObject=re.search(r"(^.*?\/(?:Accept|Integrate))(?!$).*", item)
        if matchObject :
            list.remove(item)   
        else:
            i=i+1
    return list
```

See [DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/yL9mF8/3)

Comment: awsome that did the job too :)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of matching for what you don't want, you can match what you want, with:
`^.*/(Accept|Integrate)$`

Now there is another problem with your loop: you can't remove items from a list you're iterating on! You need to work on a temporary result list.

Since you seem to want to filter the list "in place" you can use this:
`list[:] = tmp`

Here's the code:

```
import re

def filtre(list):
    tmp = []
    for item in list:
        # matchObject=re.search(r"Accept/.*/]", item) or re.search(r"(Integrate/.*/])", item)
        if re.match(r"^.*/(Accept|Integrate)$", item):
            tmp.append(item)
    list[:] = tmp


input = ["c:/project1/main/Node/Accept/testCase1/Browse.c",
"c:/project1/main/Node/Accept/testCase2/navigate.c",
"c:/project1/main/Node/Accept/testCase2/save.c",
"c:/project1/main/Node/Accept/testCase4/search.c",
"c:/project1/main/Node/Accept",
"c:/project1/main/Node/Integrate",
"c:/project1/main/Node/Accept/destroy/fullCoverage/remove.py",
"c:/project1/main/Tree/Integrate/testCase1/Browse.c",
"c:/project1/main/Tree/Integrate"
]

filtre(input)
print '\n'.join(input)
```

Result:

```
c:/project1/main/Node/Accept
c:/project1/main/Node/Integrate
c:/project1/main/Tree/Integrate
```

Comment: good idea working with a temp list but deleting entries from the same list decrease some processor treatments because the drive I'm working on is a server replicate a size of 430Gb of nodes

Comment: But you just can't delete entries while iterating on your list, it can cause undefined behavior... on my laptop the solution you've accepted gives the wrong result because the loop skips the next item after you've removed one:  
`c:/project1/main/Node/Accept/testCase2/navigate.c
c:/project1/main/Node/Accept/testCase4/search.c
c:/project1/main/Node/Accept
c:/project1/main/Node/Integrate
c:/project1/main/Tree/Integrate/testCase1/Browse.c
c:/project1/main/Tree/Integrate`  
See this post...
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6022764/python-removing-list-element-while-iterating-over-list

Comment: you were right i did a debug ,it seems that it skips some lines but i get the expected result by chance :) I'll try yours and give a feedback thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use this regex:

```
^\S+?(?:Accept|Integrate)\s*$
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/mY3jK3/1)

In Python:

```
txt='''\
c:/project1/main/Node/Accept/testCase1/Browse.c
c:/project1/main/Node/Accept/testCase2/navigate.c
c:/project1/main/Node/Accept/testCase2/save.c
c:/project1/main/Node/Accept/testCase4/search.c
c:/project1/main/Node/Accept
c:/project1/main/Node/Integrate
c:/project1/main/Node/Accept/destroy/fullCoverage/remove.py
c:/project1/main/Tree/Integrate/testCase1/Browse.c
c:/project1/main/Tree/Integrate'''

>>> re.findall(r'^\S+?(?:Accept|Integrate)\s*$', txt, re.M)
['c:/project1/main/Node/Accept', 'c:/project1/main/Node/Integrate', 'c:/project1/main/Tree/Integrate']
```

If your source is a list of strings rather than a single string, use [filter](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#filter) with the same regex:

```
>>> filter(lambda s: re.search(r'^\S+?(?:Accept|Integrate)\s*$', s), txt.splitlines())
['c:/project1/main/Node/Accept', 'c:/project1/main/Node/Integrate', 'c:/project1/main/Tree/Integrate']
```