# How do I sort an unordered list using BeautifulSoup 4 by a child element

Tags: python, sorting, python-3.x, beautifulsoup, html-lists

I am new to Python coding and BeautifulSoup4. I have a list in HTML that I need to sort, which follows the pattern:

```
<div id="mgioLangSelector">
<ul id="mgioLangList">
<li><a href="" class="mgio-autonym"><span class="mgioAutonymNative" lang="am">አማርኛ</span><span class="mgioAutonymSeperator"> / </span><span class="mgioAutonymEnglish">Amharic</span</a></li>
<li><a href="" class="mgio-autonym"><span class="mgioAutonymNative" lang="hr">hrvatski</span><span class="mgioAutonymSeperator"> / </span>        <span class="mgioAutonymEnglish">Croatian</span</a></li>
<li><a href="" class="mgio-autonym"><span class="mgioAutonymNative" lang="cs">čeština</span><span class="mgioAutonymSeperator"> / </span><span class="mgioAutonymEnglish">Czech</span</a></li>
<li><a href="" class="mgio-autonym"><span class="mgioAutonymNative" lang="vi">tiếng Việt</span><span class="mgioAutonymSeperator"> / </span><span class="mgioAutonymEnglish">Vietnamese</span</a></li>
<li><a href="" class="mgio-autonym"><span class="mgioAutonymNative" lang="sq">shqip</span><span class="mgioAutonymSeperator"> / </span><span class="mgioAutonymEnglish">Albanian</span</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

I need to sort the list *in situ* and save the resultant HTML. The list needs to be sorted by the contents of the third span, with class = mgioAutonymEnglish

I suspect that I need to use `sorted()` with an appropriate key function, but am coming up blank.

I have tried the following code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from lxml import etree
soup = BeautifulSoup(open("interimResults.html"), 'lxml', from_encoding="utf-8")
matches = soup.find_all("span", attrs={"class": "mgioAutonymEnglish"})
sorted(matches, key=lambda elem: elem.text)
```

This will sort the contents of the span, but not the lists in the original list. I assume that I need to change the lambda function, but I'm currently at a loss.

What would I need to do or change to successfully sort the list and then save those changes within the HTML document?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is actually a little more involved than you might think, so it'll help to go through it step by step.

Let's start with your `soup`:

```
>>> soup
<html><body>
...
<div id="mgioLangSelector">
<ul id="mgioLangList">
<li><a class="mgio-autonym" href=""><span class="mgioAutonymNative" lang="am">አማርኛ</span><span class="mgioAutonymSeperator"> / </span><span class="mgioAutonymEnglish">Amharic</span></a></li>
<li><a class="mgio-autonym" href=""><span class="mgioAutonymNative" lang="hr">hrvatski</span><span class="mgioAutonymSeperator"> / </span> <span class="mgioAutonymEnglish">Croatian</span></a></li>
<li><a class="mgio-autonym" href=""><span class="mgioAutonymNative" lang="cs">čeština</span><span class="mgioAutonymSeperator"> / </span><span class="mgioAutonymEnglish">Czech</span></a></li>
<li><a class="mgio-autonym" href=""><span class="mgioAutonymNative" lang="vi">tiếng Việt</span><span class="mgioAutonymSeperator"> / </span><span class="mgioAutonymEnglish">Vietnamese</span></a></li>
<li><a class="mgio-autonym" href=""><span class="mgioAutonymNative" lang="sq">shqip</span><span class="mgioAutonymSeperator"> / </span><span class="mgioAutonymEnglish">Albanian</span></a></li>
</ul>
</div>
...
</body></html>
```

The first thing to do is get hold of the `ul`:

```
ul = soup.find(attrs={"id": "mgioLangList"})
```

Now we can [`extract()`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#extract) all the `li` elements from it and store them in a list:

```
items = [li.extract() for li in ul.find_all("li")]
```

To sort the list, we need a key. You were on the right lines, but actually it needs to look like this:

```
items.sort(key=lambda e: e.find(attrs={"class": "mgioAutonymEnglish"}).string)
```

Now that we have a sorted list of `li` elements, we can insert them back into the document. What might not be immediately obvious is that the `ul` didn't just contain `li` elements – they were separated by linebreaks, which are still there:

```
>>> ul
<ul id="mgioLangList">





</ul>
```

... and in fact, they're still six separate `'\n'` strings:

```
>>> ul.contents
['\n', '\n', '\n', '\n', '\n', '\n']
```

In order to insert our sorted list of `li` elements back inbetween those linebreaks, we can use the builtin [`zip()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) function and the [`insert_after()`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#insert-before-and-insert-after) method:

```
for linebreak, li in reversed(list(zip(ul.contents, items))):
    linebreak.insert_after(li)
```

Note that, because we're modifying `ul.contents` by inserting elements as we iterate over it, it's necessary to do so [in reverse](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6024599) so that the `for` loop doesn't end up tripping over itself.

And so ...

```
>>> soup
<html><body>
...
<div id="mgioLangSelector">
<ul id="mgioLangList">
<li><a class="mgio-autonym" href=""><span class="mgioAutonymNative" lang="sq">shqip</span><span class="mgioAutonymSeperator"> / </span><span class="mgioAutonymEnglish">Albanian</span></a></li>
<li><a class="mgio-autonym" href=""><span class="mgioAutonymNative" lang="am">አማርኛ</span><span class="mgioAutonymSeperator"> / </span><span class="mgioAutonymEnglish">Amharic</span></a></li>
<li><a class="mgio-autonym" href=""><span class="mgioAutonymNative" lang="hr">hrvatski</span><span class="mgioAutonymSeperator"> / </span> <span class="mgioAutonymEnglish">Croatian</span></a></li>
<li><a class="mgio-autonym" href=""><span class="mgioAutonymNative" lang="cs">čeština</span><span class="mgioAutonymSeperator"> / </span><span class="mgioAutonymEnglish">Czech</span></a></li>
<li><a class="mgio-autonym" href=""><span class="mgioAutonymNative" lang="vi">tiếng Việt</span><span class="mgioAutonymSeperator"> / </span><span class="mgioAutonymEnglish">Vietnamese</span></a></li>
</ul>
</div>
...
</body></html>
```

Here's the whole thing:

```
ul = soup.find(attrs={"id": "mgioLangList"})
items = [li.extract() for li in ul.find_all("li")]
items.sort(key=lambda e: e.find(attrs={"class": "mgioAutonymEnglish"}).string)
for linebreak, li in reversed(list(zip(ul.contents, items))):
    linebreak.insert_after(li)
```