# How can I loop through a list of strings?

Tags: python-3.x

I have this code:

```
test = ["A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I","J","K","L","M","N","O"]

for i in test:
    if i not in ["C","D"]:
        test.remove(i)

print(test)
```

I was expecting to get `['C','D']` as a result of running the code above, however I am getting this `['B', 'C', 'D', 'F', 'H', 'J', 'L', 'N']`

How can I successfully loop through a list of strings and delete the elements I don't need using Python 3?

**NOTE:** I don't want to use comprehension lists

thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove items from a list while iterating in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1207406/remove-items-from-a-list-while-iterating-in-python)

Comment: @soon I don't want to use comprehension lists. thank you

Comment: Any reason not to use list comprehensions?

Comment: @soon this example is just an example of another piece of code and I believe using list comprehension will make my code more difficult to read

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When removing from lists in other languages, I used to reverse walk the list:

```
test = ["A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I","J","K","L","M","N","O"]

for i in reversed(test):
    if i not in ["C","D"]:
        test.remove(i)

print(test)
```

Note that `reversed` will create a new list so this might not be the best solution for large lists. Now, since you already walk a copy of your list, and if you need to parse in the correct order, you can use `copy`:

```
import copy
for i in copy.copy(test):
    if i not in ["C","D"]:
        test.remove(i)
```

and to avoid the import (from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2612802/how-to-clone-or-copy-a-list-in-python)):

```
for i in test[:]:
    if i not in ["C","D"]:
        test.remove(i)
```

Finally, the best solution for me, is a traditional, in-place reverse iteration without copying the list ("borrowed" and modified from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6024599/3727050) answer)

```
for i in range(len(test) - 1, -1, -1):
    if test[i] not in ["C","D"]:
        del test[i]
```

Comment: thank very much for this, is this much efficient than using comprehesion list?

Answer (score 0):

First loop: `i` = 'A', `i` not in ['C', 'D'] -> remove `i`. Now the first item of `test` is 'B'. So in the next loop `i` will be equal to 'C'. That is where things gone wrong...

Comment: I know this but this behaviour doesn't seem to occur when I am using a list of int.

Comment: It will occur no matter what kind of list. You can use pdb to debug and check  yourself :')