# List erasing unexpected behavior

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am trying to clear a python list by removing every element in loop by code

```
x=list(range(10000))
for i in x:
    x.remove(i)
```

I thought that after this code **x** must be **[]**, but instead only every second element of list is removed. **len(x)=5000** instead of **0**.

Why is it so? What am I doing wrong.
Thanks

Comment: Or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6022764/python-removing-list-element-while-iterating-over-list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to clear a python list like you're doing, the right way is just using `x.clear`, docs about that method [here](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists), now, if you want to remove elements using some fancy conditions, just use [filter](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#filter), example clearing the whole `x` list:

```
x = list(range(10000))
x = filter(lambda x: False, x)
print x
```

Answer (score 2):

The *a.remove(i)* messed up the indexing is my guess.

instead use

```
a.clear()
```

Its a good way to clear a list.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to implement a list object that erases itself while iterating over it that would be fairly easy:

```
class ErasingList(list):
    "a list implemented as an iterator, iterating over it will .pop() items off"
    def __iter__(self):
        return self
    def __next__(self):
        try:
            return self.pop(0)
        #or self.pop() to take from the end of the list which is less intuitive but more efficient
        except IndexError:
            raise StopIteration
    next = __next__ #vs2 compatibility.

x = ErasingList(range(100))

for i in x:
    print(i)

print(x)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
original_list = list(range(1000))
remove_list_elements = []

for i in range(0, len(original_list), 2): 
    remove_list_elements.append(original_list[i])

[original_list.remove(i) for i in remove_list_elements] 
print(len(original_list))
```