# Python: Remove items from list while iterating, which have non-trivial removal conditions

Tags: python

This is not a dupe of other questions I have found such as:

[Remove items from a list while iterating](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1207406/remove-items-from-a-list-while-iterating)

[Python: Removing list element while iterating over list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6022764/python-removing-list-element-while-iterating-over-list)

The problem is this: given a list of classes, such as abstracted sockets, what is the most Pythonic way to remove them, if there is a non-trivial way of determining if they should be removed?

```
sockets = [ socket1, socket2, socket3 ] # whatever
for sock in sockets:
    try:
        sock.close()
    except:
        pass
    else:
        remove the socket from the list here!
```

Cannot use the solution from either link. The "best" solution I can think of with my limited Python knowledge is to create a new list with only the ones that encountered exceptions appended to it.

```
sockets = [ socket1, socket2, socket3 ] # whatever
newsockets = []
for sock in sockets:
    try:
        sock.close()
    except:
        newsockets.append(sock)
sockets = newsockets
```

This still feels wrong, however. Is there a better way?

EDIT for moderator who ignored my explicit statement that the question this was marked as a dupe of is not a dupe.

To the first link I posted, you cannot use try/except in a list comprehension.
To the second link (the one it was marked as a dupe of), as the comments say, that is a bad solution. `remove(non-hashable item or item that doesn't have __eq__)` does not work.

Comment: what about using `pop()` ?

Comment: Please give us your definition of when something is *most pythonic*. If you don't have a clear definition for that, and a way to make decision about it, you'll always wonder if there is some greener grass out there.

Comment: @nexus66 `pop`-ping elements from a list over which you are walking with a `for` loop is guaranteed to give problems.

Comment: @Anthon Thanks for your comment. Can you explain which kind of problems ? Thanks.

Comment: Creating a new list, is the best way. Why does that feel wrong?

Comment: @nexus66 when you iterate and remove at the same time some elements will be skipped in your loop.

Comment: I see. Thanks @Keiwan

Comment: For every none-trivial way to filter you can write a function. So duplicate of your second link.

Comment: Your code is perfectly readable and I don't know why it feels wrong. You can't have `try..except` in a list comprehension or anything similar if that's what you would prefer. The only thing I might change is to assign the `newsockets` list to a slice of `sockets[:]`

Comment: @Keiwan can you elaborate please?
Also, anyone know why this was marked as duplicate when I specified that the other question I supposedly dupe'd does not answer my question and gave why it doesn't?

Answer (score 3):

Usually the proper way algorithmically is to build a new list, then either replace the original list with the new list, or slice it in there, if you expect to remove a substantial number of the sockets:

```
sockets = [socket1, socket2, socket3] # whatever
new_sockets = []
for sock in sockets:
    try:
        sock.close()
    except:
        new_sockets.append(sock)

sockets[:] = new_sockets
```

The reason for this is that removal of an item that is at an arbitrary location (e.g. by using `sockets.remove`) within the list of `n` items will have time complexity of `O(n)` on average, and if you end up removing `k` items, then the total complexity will be of `O(kn)`, whereas constructing a new list and replacing the original with new will have time complexity of the scale of `O(n)`, i.e. it doesn't depend on the number of sockets removed.

---

Or, as sockets are hashable, perhaps you should use a set to store them instead. Then, you need to either construct a new collection from the set to make it possible to iterate and remove at the same time (here I am using a list):

```
sockets = {socket1, socket2, socket3}
for sock in list(sockets):
    try:
        sock.close()
    except: 
        pass
    else:
        sockets.discard(sock)
```

Creating a new list has O(n) time complexity, but `set.discard` has only O(1) complexity.

Another way which gets rid of copying the data structure is to use another set for items that are to be *removed*:

```
sockets = {socket1, socket2, socket3}
to_remove = set()   # create an initially empty set
for sock in sockets:
    try:
        sock.close()
    except: 
        pass
    else:
        to_remove.add(sock)

# remove all sockets that are in to_remove in one 
# operation from sockets.
sockets.difference_update(to_remove)
```

This has a favourable running time over the other set example in case there are very few if any items to be removed.

Comment: Excellent ideas and thank you for giving an informed and educational answer!

Answer (score 0):

*This answer only adds a little explanation as to why you might want to assign the result to a slice of your original list. @Antti Happala has already given some nice alternatives for potentially improving the runtime.*

When you write

```
sockets = newsockets
```

you are assigning the new list to the variable named `sockets`, whereas if you say

```
sockets[:] = newsockets
```

you are essentially replacing the entries of the **same list** with the new list.

The difference becomes more clear if you previously had another reference to your `sockets` list like so:

```
s = sockets
```

then, after assigning without slicing, `s` would still point to the old list with none of the sockets removed and `sockets` would refer to the new list.

Using the slicing version both `s` and `sockets` would refer to the same, updated list after removing some elements.

Usually this in-place replacement is what you want, however, there are also times when you might specifically want `s` and `sockets` to refer to different versions of the list, in which case you should not assign to a list slice. It all depends.