# Duplicate output when iterating over a set

Tags: python-3.x, intellij-idea

I'm having trouble understanding why I am receiving repeat output when I iterate over a set of letters and remove letters that are contained within another set.

Code

```
text = set(input("Please enter some text: ").lower())
vowels = {"a", "e", "i", "o", "u", "y", ' '}

for t in text:
    if t in vowels:
        new_text = (text-vowels)
        print(sorted(new_text))
```

example:

```
Please enter some text: camera
['c', 'm', 'r']
['c', 'm', 'r']
```

Comment: I am trying to cut the double output ie. ['c', 'm', 'r']

Answer (score -1, accepted):

By altering the set, the output works as follows...

```html
text = input("Please enter some text: ").lower()
vowels = {"a", "e", "i", "o", "u", "y", ' '}

new_text = set(text)
for t in text:
    if t in vowels:
        new_text.discard(t)

print(sorted(new_text))
```

output...

```html
Please enter some text: camera
['c', 'm', 'r']
```

Answer (score -1):

The print happens the same number of times as the number of non-vowels in text.

### Correct approach

Make a copy of the set or create the set from text separately.

To make a copy of the set

```
new_set = old_set.copy() #and check the id() values for both here
```

To create a set from text separately

```
input_ = input("Please enter some text: ").lower()

text = set(input_)
vowels = {"a", "e", "i", "o", "u", "y", ' '}

#To remove the vowel one-by-one by iterating
new_text = set(input_)
for t in text:
    if t in vowels:
        new_text.discard(t) # or remove
```

### To print the non-vowels at one-go

```
print(sorted(new_text))
```

### Error in previous answer

1. Removing elements while iterating over it.
   [Python: Removing list element while iterating over list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6022764/python-removing-list-element-while-iterating-over-list2).
2. I was pointing both the text and new_text to the same set.
   We can confirm this by 'is' operator.

   text is new_text #Returns True

   print(id(text)), print(id(new_text)) #have the same value, so changing 
   one changes the other

### Previous Answer (Incorrect)

```
text = set(input("Please enter some text: ").lower())
vowels = {"a", "e", "i", "o", "u", "y", ' '}

#To remove the vowel one-by-one by iterating
new_text = text
for t in text:
    if t in vowels:
        new_text.discard(t) # or remove

#To print the non-vowels at one-go
print(sorted(new_text))
```

Comment: This yields RuntimeError: Set changed size during iteration

Comment: I fixed the problem using that code but changing: text = input("Please enter some text: ").lower()): new_text = set(text)

Comment: @ChrisOlson I added the correct answer by editing the solution. Please check that out.