# List Comprehension Example

Tags: python, list

How could I do the below code with a list comprehension. I have been looking at these examples, but I can't figure it out :|

[Python: Removing list element while iterating over list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6022764/python-removing-list-element-while-iterating-over-list)

```
list_dicts = [{'site': 'living', 'status': 'ready' }, {'site': 'keg', 
'status': 'ready' }, {'site': 'box', 'status': 'ready' }, {'site': 'wine', 
'status': 'not_ready' }]

def call_some_func(m_site_dict):
     print "I executed the 'call_something_function'"

for site in list_dicts[:]:
    if site['status'] == 'ready':
        call_some_func(site)
        list_dicts.remove(site)
```

Comment: `list_dicts = [{'site': site, 'status': 'ready' if site != 'wine' else 'not_ready'} for site in ['living', 'keg', 'box', 'wine']]`, but note that I would write exactly what you have.

Comment: if you mean how would you use a list comprehension in place of the for loop, you wouldn't. List comprehensions are a way concisely create lists, not a drop-in replacement for a for loop.

Comment: @AdamSmith ah ok, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not a great idea to replace this for loop because you are making a function call with side effects (currently printing). You can use an else clause to construct a new list, which would be more performant (`O(1)` for `append()` vs `O(n)` for `del`)  e.g.:

```
In []:
new_list_dicts = []
for site in list_dicts:
    if site['status'] == 'ready':
        call_some_func(site)
    else:
        new_list_dicts.append(site)
new_list_dicts

Out[]:
I executed the 'call_something_function'
I executed the 'call_something_function'
I executed the 'call_something_function'

[{'site': 'wine', 'status': 'not_ready'}]
```

Just as a demonstration (but very bad form) you can do this as a list comprehension but it relies on short-circuiting and the fact the `call_some_func()` returns `None` which is considered `False`:

```
In []:
[site for site in list_dicts if site['status'] == 'ready' and 
 call_some_func(site) or site['status'] != 'ready']

Out[]:
I executed the 'call_something_function'
I executed the 'call_something_function'
I executed the 'call_something_function'

[{'site': 'wine', 'status': 'not_ready'}]
```