# For loop statement not reading if statement to continue to next iteration

Tags: python, for-loop, if-statement, twilio, continue

I have code that looks like this:

```
for item in items:

    if item.data["position"] == '5':
        item.delete() 
        continue
    elif item.data["lang"] == 'SPA':
        message_body = my_message_spa[item.data["position"]]
    else:
        message_body = my_message_eng[item.data["position"]] # English (default)

    message = client.messages.create(
        item.data["phone_number"],                    
        body=message_body,
        from_="xxxx"                           
    )
    # increment the position for this user
    item.data["position"]+=1
```

This code is meant to send messages to an user. 
Items is a list of dictionaries that has an user's phone number, date, language, and position. 
Position refers to their position in the sequence of messages.
I would like to check the position of a user and if they have already received `5` messages, then it should be removed from the list and continue on to the next user. If the position of the user is `<5` then it should go into the `else if` statements and send messages according to the conditions met.

The list of dictionaries has the following structure:

```
{'phone_number': '+1234567890', 'position': 5, 'lang': 'ENG', 'Date': '2018-08-17 00:03:46'}
{'phone_number': '+0987654321', 'position': 2, 'lang': 'ENG', 'Date': '2018-12-18 07:10:47'}
```

The code worked fine previously and the new part I am adding/testing is the if statement checking for position but it seems like that if statement does not get invoked at all and goes straight to the below `elif` checking for `'lang'` and sends the message and increments the position for the user. In my case, the user's position gets incremented to `6`.

Comment: try removing '' from '5', 5 is integer so check with only 5

Comment: What happens if you remove the quotes around 5?

Comment: Also, you are calling `delete()` on a dict object. You might want to use `items.remove(item)` instead

Answer (score 3):

You seem to be comparing the value incorrectly. You are trying to compare a string "5" to an integer 5.

```
if item.data["position"] == '5':
```

note the quotes around 5.

For example:

```
print(1 == "1")
print(1 == 1)
```

returns False for the first one, and True for the second one.

You also should not delete items from something like a list when iterating over it. Instead try creating a copy or using list comprehension.

Comment: Sorry, I am fairly new to python and got handed this project. Thank you for the help. Could you expand on your last sentence on why I should not delete items from a list? Or what did you mean by making a copy or using list comprehension? The examples I found online shows list comprehension being used to iterate over a string.

Comment: I mean that you cannot modify the thing's index you are iterating over. The for loop is going to think there are x items in the list, and if you remove one, it's still going to try to access that many items. You can [make a copy of the list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6022764/python-removing-list-element-while-iterating-over-list) and only edit the original list, which does not mess up the for loop. Or [list comprehension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1207406/how-to-remove-items-from-a-list-while-iterating), e.g. somelist = [x for x in somelist if not x["position"] == 5]