# For loop requires more than an iteration to be completed

Tags: python

I was doing some stuff in Python, and i faced a strange behaviour of a for loop. What I was trying to do is to delete an element of a list when a certain condition is met:

```py
for l, line in enumerate(lines):
  temp = line.split()
  if '_' not in temp[0]:
    del lines[l]
```

But, when I execute this code, the list named `lines` still contains words without the underscore on the first element of a line. So, I tried to reiterate the same code through checking the length of `lines` before and after the execution of the code:

```py
temp1 = 1
temp2 = 0
while temp1 != temp2:
  temp1 = len(lines)
  for l, line in enumerate(lines):
    temp = line.split()
    if '_' not in temp[0]:
      del lines[l]
  temp2 = len(lines)
  print(temp1,temp2)
```

And what i get in output is confirming that this for loop requires more than an iteration to be completed:

```
82024 57042
57042 44880
44880 38908
38908 36000
36000 34611
34611 33937
33937 33612
33612 33454
33454 33378
33378 33343
33343 33327
33327 33320
33320 33317
33317 33315
33315 33315
```

Anyone can explain why?

Comment: Don't remove elements from a list while iterating over it. If you need to, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6022764/python-removing-list-element-while-iterating-over-list?noredirect=1&lq=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should, in general, never change something you are iterating over. You want to change your code so that you create a new list instead of deleting items.

```
new_temp = []
for l, line in enumerate(lines):
  temp = line.split()
  if '_' in temp[0]:
    new_temp.append(lines[l])
```