# How to remove urls from file which has 404 status code using python remove function?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have to remove urls from a file which has 404 status using python remove function. But I am not sure why it is not working.

Code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import requests



url_lines = open('url.txt').read().splitlines()
for url in url_lines:
    remove_url = requests.get(url)
    if remove_url.status_code == 404:
       print remove_url.status_code
       url_lines.remove(url)
```

url.txt file contains following lines:

```
https://www.amazon.co.uk/jksdkkhsdhk
http://www.google.com
```

Line https://www.amazon.co.uk/jksdkkhsdhk should be removed from url.txt file.

Thank you so much for help in advance.

Comment: maybe this will help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6022764/python-removing-list-element-while-iterating-over-list

Comment: i think once the status code gets checked, you can just skip the status code check line afterwards and remove the url with `url_lines.remove(remove_url)` granted `url_lines` should be a list for that to happen.

Comment: If you want the 404-urls to be dropped/removed from the `txt` file, you will need to write the updated list of valid urls to the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just skip it:

```py
if remove_url.status_code == 404:
    continue
```

You shouldn't try to remove it while inside the `for` loop. Instead, add it to another list `remove_from_urls` and, after your `for` loop, remove all the indices in your new list. This could be done by:

```py
remove_from_urls = []

for url in url_lines:
    remove_url = requests.get(url)
    if remove_url.status_code == 404:
        remove_from_urls.append(url)
        continue
    # Code for handling non-404 requests

url_lines = [url for url in url_lines if url not in remove_from_urls]

# Save urls example
with open('urls.txt', 'w+') as file:
    for item in url_lines:
        file.write(item + '\n')
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, I tried running your code but not effect. I still see 404 url in url.txt file. I think last line from your code which is out of for loop should update url.txt file, right?

Comment: @rmstmg you are right, I didn't update the file. You just need to store each item in `url_lines`. Will update the code :-)