# Remove related element from list while iterating in python

Tags: python, list

I need to reduce the size of a list iteratively based on an equivalence condition. The idea is that I iterate in the list and, for each element, I eliminate all the elements of the list related (equivalent) to that element.

For example, consider that `G` is a list of tuples. I want to eliminate all tuples that can be obtained as a permutation of another tuple already in the list. Let `equiv(g)` be the function that returns a list of all permutations of `g` (excluding `g` itself).

I tried this code:

```
for g in G:
    for gg in equiv(g):
        if gg in GN:
            G.remove(gg)
```

This should leave in the list only one element for each equivalence class.
However, it doesn't seem to work properly. I suspect I am doing it the wrong way.

Note that I cannot iterate over a copy of the list `G`, as suggested for example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6022764/python-removing-list-element-while-iterating-over-list), because in this way all elements of each class of equivalence would be removed. In other words, I don't want to remove based on elements what have already been removed.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Strange result when removing item from a list while iterating over it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6260089/strange-result-when-removing-item-from-a-list-while-iterating-over-it)

Comment: Is the order of the list important? You need to remove equivalents of the first elements in the list first?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For loop iterate through the list by incrementing the indexes, which will have problems if you delete elements and refreshes the index. Try to use while loop + pop

```
new_G = []
while len(G) > 0: # while G: 
    g = G.pop(0)
    for gg in equiv(g):
        G.remove(gg)
    new_G.append(g)
```

Comment: This seems the right approach, but don't use the keyword `next` as a variable name

Comment: It seems that instead of `next` it should be `g`. Also you can use `while G:`.

Comment: If you make the correction, I accept this answer as the one which solves my problem