# How do I pop a stack till it's empty using a FOR loop?

Tags: python, list, for-loop, stack

```
S=['TOM', 'HARRY', 'MAMA', 'JOE']
print(S)
for x in S:
    print(S.pop())
    if S==[]:
        print("Empty")
        break
```

Using a for loop should iterate through the entire list and give me all the items followed by 'Empty' but instead, it only gives two elements

What I'm getting-

```
['TOM', 'HARRY', 'MAMA', 'JOE']
JOE
MAMA
```

What I was expecting-

```
['TOM', 'HARRY', 'MAMA', 'JOE']
JOE
MAMA
HARRY
TOM
Empty
```

This is my first question here so any tips on how to frame questions would be appreciated.

Comment: ***This might help:*** https://stackoverflow.com/q/6022764/12769604

Answer (score 2):

The main issue with your code is that you can't loop over a list while doing changes to that list. If you want to use a `for` loop (timgeb suggestion is great btw). You could do this:

```py
for _ in range(len(S)):
    print(S.pop())
```

This will take care of popping all the items of the list

Answer (score 1):

You see an unexpected result because you're mutating the list while iterating over it. Note that you're not doing anything with `x`, so a `for` loop is not the right tool here.

Use a `while` loop.

```
while S:
    print(S.pop())

print('empty')
```

Comment: Functionally correct but OP specifically stated that he wants a *for* loop

Comment: @AlbertWinestein OP doesn't know what he wants.

Comment: @timgeb I did know that you could use a while loop, I just wanted to know why you can't use a for loop like that so thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
S=['TOM', 'HARRY', 'MAMA', 'JOE']
print(S)
for x in S[::-1]:
    print(S.pop())
    if S==[]:
        print("Empty")
        break
```

Comment: This won't work as you are attempting to modify a list that you are using to iterate into