# Is python's "in" language construct thread-safe for lists?

Tags: python, list, thread-safety, in-operator

Is `obj in a_list` thread-safe while `a_list` might be modified in a different thread?

[Here's a comprehensive yet non-exhaustive list of examples](http://effbot.org/pyfaq/what-kinds-of-global-value-mutation-are-thread-safe.htm) of `list` operations and whether or not they are thread safe, however I couldn't find any reference for the `in` language construct.

In terms of python implementation, I use CPython, but answers re other implementations would be helpful too for the community.

Comment: Note that any statement about thread safety is implementation specific (and perhaps version-specific too). It's probably easier to assume nothing is thread safe except taking and releasing a lock.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I am assuming you are using CPython here.

Provided there is no custom `__contains__` or `__iter__` hook dropping back into Python *or* the values you test against contained *in* the list use custom `__eq__` hooks implemented in Python code, the `in` operator can be handled entirely in C, and is just *one* opcode.

This makes the operation entirely thread-safe; Python threads only switch *between* opcodes; the GIL (global interpreter lock) normally only unlocks between opcodes.

That said, if you use `in` on a custom C type that unlocks the GIL when testing containment would not be thread-safe.

In other words: the `in` bytecode test is locked, but if the operator needs to call Python code (through `__contains__`, iterating with `__iter__` when no `__contains__` implementation is available, or the values are test against `__eq__` hooks implemented in Python), then the operation is not thread safe.

For other Python implementations, how threading is handled can vary widely. Certainly, Jython and IronPython have no GIL, and you should assume the operation is *not* thread safe.