# Python threads to accumulate items to a collection

Tags: python, multithreading

I have threads to add items to let's say a global success list.

I know that thread communications should be done via `Queue`s, but when reading the Queue [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/queue.html), there is no function to get exact count of the queue length.

> Queue.qsize() Return the approximate size of the queue. Note, qsize()
>
> > 0 doesn’t guarantee that a subsequent get() will not block, nor will qsize() < maxsize guarantee that put() will not block.

I have also tried `len(queue)` but it doesn't work:

```
>>> import Queue
>>> q = Queue.Queue()
>>> q.put(1)
>>> q.put(2)
>>> len(q)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: Queue instance has no attribute '__len__'
```

I have also read about using `List` but I [don't have definite answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6319207/are-lists-thread-safe) if the data will be corrupted or not.

My only option I can think of right now is to run `queue.get()` until `queue` is empty to convert to a list. Is there a better choice?

Comment: Why not subclass `Queue` and add your own `length` function or implement `__len__`? This is probably a bad idea and there's no guarantee it will be be thread safe, but it's worth a shot.

Comment: Also, why is `qsize()` not sufficient?

Comment: I think when I read the documentation, it says "return the approximate size of the queue", what I need is after the thread execution block, at the end of the main thread to work out how many items in the queue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason `qsize` doesn't give these guarantees is because between calling `.qsize()` and `.get()` some other thread may insert an element. Other then that you should use `qsize`. It will give you an **exact** size of the queue at the moment of calling. The word "approximate" here means that after that moment of calling the size is no longer guaranteed to be the same. But when dealing with threads accessing shared data structure you will always face the same issue, no matter what the structure is.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying.