# Extracting keys and values from a dictionary in Python (in a thread-safe manner)

Tags: python, dictionary, thread-safety

I have a simple function for extracting keys and values from a dictionary.

```
def separate_kv_fast(adict):
    '''Separates keys/values from a dictionary to corresponding arrays'''
    return adict.keys(), adict.values()
```

I know the order is guaranteed if the dictionary "adict" is not modified between the .keys() and .values() call. What I am wondering is if the return statement guarantees this; basically, is it going to be thread safe?

Is the following construction of "adict" any safer for multi-threading or not-needed?

```
def separate_kv_fast(adict):
    '''Separates keys/values from a dictionary to corresponding arrays'''
    bdict = dict(adict)
    return bdict.keys(), bdict.values()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've been working on learning python disassembly, and I believe this shows the two calls are not atomic:

```
>>> dis.dis(separate_kv_fast)                                                                             
  2           0 LOAD_FAST                0 (adict)
              3 LOAD_ATTR                0 (keys)
              6 CALL_FUNCTION            0
              9 LOAD_FAST                0 (adict)
             12 LOAD_ATTR                1 (values)
             15 CALL_FUNCTION            0
             18 BUILD_TUPLE              2
             21 RETURN_VALUE        
>>>
```

That it calls keys and values across multiple opcodes I believe demonstrates it is not atomic.

Let's see how your `bdict = dict(adict)` works out:

```
  2           0 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (dict)
              3 LOAD_FAST                0 (adict)
              6 CALL_FUNCTION            1
              9 STORE_FAST               1 (bdict)
```

`LOAD_FAST` pushes a reference to `adict` onto the stack.  We then call `dict` with that argument.  What we don't know is if `dict()` function is atomic.

`bdict = adict.copy()` gives a similar disassembly.  `adict.copy` can't be disassembled.

Everything I read says that internal types are thread safe.  So I believe a single function call into a dictionary would be internally consistent.  i.e., `items()`, `copy()`, `values()`, `keys()`, etc.  Two calls in serial (`values()` followed by `keys()` aren't necessarilly safe.  Neither are iterators.

Is there a reason your not just using `items()`?

I was curious, so went ahead and benchmarked:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import timeit
import random

D = dict()
for x in xrange(0, 1000):
    D[x] = str(x)

def a():
    return D.keys(), D.values()

def b():
    keys = []
    values = []
    for k, v in D.items():
        keys.append(k)
        values.append(v)
    return keys, values

def c():
    d = D.copy()
    return d.keys(), d.values()

def d():
    return zip(*D.items())

print timeit.timeit("a()", 'from __main__ import a')
print timeit.timeit("b()", 'from __main__ import b')
print timeit.timeit("c()", 'from __main__ import c')
print timeit.timeit("d()", 'from __main__ import d')
```

Results:

```
6.56165385246
145.151810169
19.9027020931
65.4051799774
```

The copy is the fasted atomic one (and might be slightly faster than using dict()).

Comment: The disassembled version definitely adds insight. My first version generate_kv() uses .items()/.iteritems() which is certainly safer, but then requires iteration over them to extract the keys and values with some speed penalty. It's not much but I got curious especially since I am considering using multiprocessing or multi-threading to generate the dictionary. Thanks!

Comment: `iteritems()` I would expect to have issues since it is reentrant.  `items()` just returns a list of key value pairs.  I would expect it to be as safe (and slow) as `copy()`

Comment: You realize if you use `multiprocessing`, the objects are not shared over the processes?  So concurrency of your dictionary is not a problem.   You might be interested in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37890199/reduce-execution-time-on-huge-list-generation) that I answered -- it was a large list being generated over `multiprocessing`.