# Concurrent access to list from multiple threads in python when data is appended constantly

Tags: python, multithreading, list, thread-safety

We have a list to which data is appended at regular time intervals and this procedure takes time so using usual mutex to protect the entire list during writes is not the most efficient solution. How to organize reads and writes to such list in a more concurrent fashion?

Comment: [Related.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6319207/are-lists-thread-safe)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You don't need locking when using `list.append()` or `list.extend()` with multiple threads. These operations are thread-safe.

Here is a brief overview of operations that are thread-safe: https://docs.python.org/3/faq/library.html#what-kinds-of-global-value-mutation-are-thread-safe

It's also worth mentioning that from a performance standpoint it's much faster to prepare sub-lists in separate threads, and then `extend` the main list with these sub-lists.

Comment: correct me if im wrong, python lists are implemented with arrays, not dynamic structures. So when list is full a new allocation is required. But how can threads be informed about that case? Threads may try to append a data to a full list. I am wondering how that safety is provided.

Comment: I think it's because of the global interpreter lock. The Python VM will not execute code from different threads at the same time, instead it quickly switches back & forth between them.

Comment: They're thread-safe. Does that mean they're also multiprocessing-safe?

Comment: How about list assignments when it's guaranteed that the threads won't access the same list item? Typical use-case when you compute parallelly and you gather results in an array.