# Can list.append(foo) be not thread-safe?

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, append

I've used multi-threading a lot, while appending to the same list from different threads. Everything worked fine.

However, I'm getting a problem with list appending when the threads are like 70 threads or more. Appending in the last thread gets stuck for like 5 mins (the processor is not occubied at this time, maybe 10 %. So, it's not a hardware problem I would say). Then appending occurs successfully.

At this [link](https://docs.python.org/3/faq/library.html#what-kinds-of-global-value-mutation-are-thread-safe), it says that list appending is thread-safe.

**My question is: Can list appending ever become not thread safe?**

Don't ask for a code or so. I just need a simple yes or no to my question. And if yes, kindly provide suggestions to fix that.

Comment: The thread safety is effectively [achieved by Python through the GIL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6319207/are-lists-thread-safe) and with 70 threads it is possible for a single thread to be locked out and not be able to do anything for quite some time as only one will be executing at a time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **list appending in python is thread safe.**

For more details: [what kinds of global value mutation are thread safe](https://docs.python.org/3/faq/library.html#what-kinds-of-global-value-mutation-are-thread-safe)

You last thread gets stuck maybe due to other reason, for example: Memory allocating..

My first step to fix the stuck is use `strace` to trace the syscall.

And you can use `gdb` to print all threads' call stack too. Here is a wiki page: https://wiki.python.org/moin/DebuggingWithGdb

Comment: Source for your quote?

Comment: @AbrahamMurcianoBenzadon, this may be your [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19728536/2089675)

Comment: @AbrahamMurcianoBenzadon https://docs.python.org/3/faq/library.html#what-kinds-of-global-value-mutation-are-thread-safe