# Python Lists and Thread Safety

Tags: python, multithreading

I am using multiple threads to work through items in a very large list untell it is empty.

```
while item_list:
    my_item = item_list.pop()
```

I check if any items are left in list and if so I pop one and work on it.  Is this process thread safe?

Is there chance that when I check there is an item in list but by time I pop it will be gone and raise error?  Or any other issues?

Comment: "Is there chance that when I check there is an item in list but by time I pop"

Yes in this case. You can hit the case where two threads have gotten past the "while item_list" but have not yet executed the pop. You should use a [thread lock](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/threading.html)

Comment: I'm curious, what operations are the threads performing?

Comment: So I surround the code with lock.acquire() and lock.release(). The code is also updating the data it collects into dictionarys.  There are no duplicates in item_list and they used as keys in dictionary. So threads may be updating the same dictionary at same time but will never be updating same key at same time. Would that be thread safe?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, a thread-switch could happen between the the two lines and the list could be empty by the time you pop the item.  Use a thread-safe `queue.Queue()` to store your work items.

Comment: Out of curiosity: Is `pop` itself thread-safe? So could the threads simply pop without checking first, in a try-except? Or could a thread-switch happen during `pop`'s execution?

Comment: @HeapOverflow Yes, the pop itself is thread-safe, so you could catch the exception if it comes up empty, but see [Are lists thread-safe?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6319267/235698).  Better to use a `queue`.  It's difficult to tell what methods are safe.