# Thread safety in python lists

Tags: python, multithreading, thread-safety

I have a list in a multithreaded program. The main thread adds elements to the list (using `list.append()`)& deletes elements from a list (using `list.pop()`). The other threads checks for existence of particular elements in the list (using `if x in list`)

No existing element in the list is ever modified (I am considering removal of elements as not a modification of an element).

From python docs, it looks as if these operations are all thread safe & I don't need to do any locking/unlocking myself. Am I correct in this assumption?

Comment: Does <https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6319207/are-lists-thread-safe> answer your question?

Comment: I also found quite useful this explanation in one of the answers of the questions linked before: <https://web.archive.org/web/20201108091210/http://effbot.org/pyfaq/what-kinds-of-global-value-mutation-are-thread-safe.htm>

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Are lists thread-safe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6319207/are-lists-thread-safe). (You are correct in your assumption).