# Updating variables passed into threads python

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, python-multithreading

I am currently having issues to do with my understanding of threading or possibly my understanding of how variables are passed/assigned thru threads in python. I have this simple program that takes in a list of current stocks that are displayed on a screen and grabs the stock information related to those. I am using threads so that I can constantly update the screen and constantly collect data. I am having two issues:

1. Inside `dataCollector_thread()` i understand that if i append to the `stocksOnScreenListInfo` that the variable (`stocksOnScreenListInfo`) inside `main` is updated.

However I don't want to append to the list but rather just reassign the list like the following  but this does not work?.

```
def dataCollector_thread(stocksOnScreenListInfo, stocksOnScreen):
    while(True):
        placeholder = []
        for stock in stocksOnScreen:
            placeholer.append(RetrieveQuote(stock))
        stocksOnScreenListInfo = placeholder
        time.sleep(5)
```

2. Inside `screenUpdate_thread` i am wanting to update `stocksOnScreen` to the variable 'TSLA' defined by the function `UpdateScreen`. This does not seem to update its corresponding `stocksOnScreen` in `main` as when I print to check it continues to say 'AAPL'?

   ```
   def main(args): 

    stocksOnScreen = ["AAPL"] # List of the stocks currently displayed on LED screen

    stocksOnScreenListInfo = [] # The quote information list for each stock on screen 

    thread_data_collector = threading.Thread(target=dataCollector_thread, args=(stocksOnScreenListInfo,stocksOnScreen))
    thread_data_collector.daemon = True
    thread_data_collector.start()

    thread_screen = threading.Thread(target=screenUpdate_thread, args=(stocksSearchArray,stocksOnScreen))
    thread_screen.daemon = True
    thread_screen.start()



    def dataCollector_thread(stocksOnScreenListInfo, stocksOnScreen):
        while(True):
            for stock in stocksOnScreen:
                stocksOnScreenListInfo.append(RetrieveQuote(stock))
            time.sleep(5)

    def screenUpdate_thread(stocksSearchArray, stocksOnScreen):
        while(True):
            stocksOnScreen = UpdateScreen(stocksSearchArray)


    def UpdateScreen(stocksSearchArray):
        pass

    return ["TSLA"]
   ```

Answer (score 3):

There are a couple of issues with this function:

> ```
> def dataCollector_thread(stocksOnScreenListInfo, stocksOnScreen):
>     while(True):
>         placeholder = []
>         for stock in stocksOnScreen:
>             placeholer.append(RetrieveQuote(stock))
>         stocksOnScreenListInfo = placeholder
>         time.sleep(5)
> ```

- you're assigning `stocksOnScreenListInfo` within this function to a new list `placeholder`. What you want to do is modify the contents in-place so that `stocksOnScreenListInfo` in `main` is updated. You can do that like this: `stocksOnScreenListInfo[:] = placeholder` (which means change contents from beginning to end with the new list).
- `stocksOnScreen` could change while you're iterating it in the for loop since you're updating it in another thread. You should do this atomically. A [lock](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#lock-objects)
  (that you pass as a parameter to the function) will help here: it's a synchronisation primitive that is designed to prevent data races when multiple threads share data and at least one of them modifies it.

I can't see `stocksOnScreenListInfo` being used anywhere else in your code. Is it used in another function? If so, you should think about having a lock around that.

I would modify the function like this:

```
def dataCollector_thread(stocksOnScreenListInfo, stocksOnScreen, lock):
    while True:
        placeholder = []
        with lock: # use lock to ensure you atomically access stocksOnScreen
            for stock in stocksOnScreen:
                placeholder.append(RetrieveQuote(stock))
        stocksOnScreenListInfo[:] = placeholder  # modify contents of stocksOnScreenListInfo
        time.sleep(5)
```

In your other thread function:

> ```
> def screenUpdate_thread(stocksSearchArray, stocksOnScreen):
>      while(True):
>          stocksOnScreen = UpdateScreen(stocksSearchArray)
> ```

you're assigning `stocksOnScreen` to a new list within this function; it won't affect `stocksOnScreen` in `main`. Again you can do that using the notation `stocksOnScreen[:] = new_list`. I would lock before before updating `stocksOnScreen` to ensure your other thread function `dataCollector_thread` accesses `stocksOnScreen` atomically like so:

```
def screenUpdate_thread(stocksSearchArray, stocksOnScreen, lock):
    while True:
        updated_list = UpdateScreen() # build new list - doesn't have to be atomic

        with lock:
            stocksOnScreen[:] = updated_list  # update contents of stocksOnScreen

        time.sleep(0.001)
```

As you can see I put in a small sleep, otherwise the function will loop constantly and be too CPU-intensive. Plus it will give Python a chance to context switch between your thread functions.

Finally, in `main` create a lock:

```
lock = threading.Lock()
```

and pass `lock` to both functions as a parameter.

Comment: I wonder if the lock is even necessary anymore with the `list[:] = ` approach (in other words, will it not be blocked by the iteration in the other thread?)

Comment: @TomYan There is no such guarantee. Even though Python has a global interpreter lock, there is still a potential race condition when one thread is iterating a list and another thread mutates the same list. It's better to protect against it using a lock.

Comment: I just wonder what's the exact definition for python list being thread-safe...

Answer (score 0):

`stocksOnScreen = ...` changes the *reference* itself. Since the reference is passed to the function/thread as a parameter, the change is done to the *copy* of the original *reference* within the function/thread. (Both function/thread have their own copy.)

So instead you should manipulate the list *object* it refers to (e.g. `list.clear()` and `list.extend()`).

However, as you can see, it's now no longer an *atomic* action. So there are chances that `dataCollector_thread` would be working on an empty list (i.e. do nothing) and sleep 5 seconds. I provided a possible workaround/solution below as well. Not sure if it is supposed to work (perfectly) though:

```
def dataCollector_thread(stocksOnScreen):
    while(True):
        sos_copy = stocksOnScreen.copy() # *might* avoid the race?
        for stock in sos_copy:
            print(stock)
        if (len(sos_copy) > 0): # *might* avoid the race?
            time.sleep(5)

def UpdateScreen():
    return ["TSLA"]

def screenUpdate_thread(stocksOnScreen):
    while(True):
        # manipulate the list object instead of changing the reference (copy) in the function
        stocksOnScreen.clear()
        # race condition: dataCollector_thread might work on an empty list and sleep 5 seconds
        stocksOnScreen.extend(UpdateScreen())

def main():
    stocksOnScreen = ["AAPL"] # List of the stocks currently displayed on LED screen

    thread_data_collector = threading.Thread(target=dataCollector_thread, args=(stocksOnScreen,)) # note the comma
    thread_data_collector.daemon = True
    thread_data_collector.start()

    thread_screen = threading.Thread(target=screenUpdate_thread, args=(stocksOnScreen,)) # note the comma
    thread_screen.daemon = True
    thread_screen.start()
```

Note: according to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6319267/5439097), python lists are thread-safe, so the copy workaround *should* work.

---

You can probably make use of [`global`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-global-statement) instead of passing `stocksOnScreen` as parameter as well:

```
def dataCollector_thread():
    global stocksOnScreen # superfluous if no re-assignment
    while(True):
        for stock in stocksOnScreen:
            print(stock)
        time.sleep(5)

def UpdateScreen():
    return ["TSLA"]

def screenUpdate_thread():
    global stocksOnScreen # needed for re-assignment
    while(True):
        stocksOnScreen = UpdateScreen()

def main():
    global stocksOnScreen # Or create stocksOnScreen outside main(), which is a function itself
    stocksOnScreen = ["AAPL"] # List of the stocks currently displayed on LED screen

    thread_data_collector = threading.Thread(target=dataCollector_thread)
    thread_data_collector.daemon = True
    thread_data_collector.start()

    thread_screen = threading.Thread(target=screenUpdate_thread)
    thread_screen.daemon = True
    thread_screen.start()
```

Ref.: https://docs.python.org/3/faq/programming.html#what-are-the-rules-for-local-and-global-variables-in-python

Answer (score 0):

You have three options here since, python like java passes parameters by value & not reference.

First, use a global parameter.

```
def threadFunction():
    globalParam = "I've ran"

global globalParam
threading.Thread(target=threadFunction)
```

Second, an Updater Function

```
def threadFunction(update):
    update("I've ran")

threading.Thread(target=threadFunction, args=((lambda x: print(x)),))
```

Third, Expose global parameter holder

```
def threadFunction(param1, param2):
    globalParams[0]= param1 + " Just Got access"

global globalParams
globalParams = ["Param1","Param2"]
threading.Thread(target=threadFunction, args=(*globalParams))
```

I hope this answered your question ;)