# How to properly parallelize and append a for loop?

Tags: python, python-3.x, parallel-processing, python-multiprocessing, joblib

I have a for loop below that runs a few functions and appends the result to a list. The list 'results' will end up with 12 elements (3 functions x 4 loop iterations = 12).

How can I parallelize this? Since my loop will iterate 4 times, does that mean I can only use 4 threads/cores?

```
results = []
for points in [250, 500, 1000, 4000]:

    df_dx, db_dy = simulate_cointegration(num_points=points, stax=0.0100, stay=0.0050, coex=0.0200, 
                                           coey=0.0200)

    johansen_results = johansen_test(df_dx, db_dy)
    cadf_results = cadf_test(df_dx, db_dy) 
    po_results = po_test(df_dx, db_dy) 

    results.append(johansen_results)
    results.append(cadf_results)
    results.append(po_results)
```

Comment: You should be able to use 4 threads to compute your pairs of (df_dx, df_dy), then birth new threads from the previous ones to process your 3 operations (johansen_test, cadf_test, po_test). I am no expert but, as far as I know, the number of threads per core will be limited by the number of threads you start in your program as well as your hardware.

Comment: Threads and core are different, in python all threads runs on the same core due to the GIL. If your process is CPU intensive threads won't help you, but [multiprocessing](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html) (mp) will. The limit for mp is usually the number of cores you have (now a days, around 8 for a decent computer), unless your processes are memory intensive (IO bound), in any case need to interact with a lot of data from and to disk, in that case you can generally run more (as long as you don't hit the IO bound).

Answer (score 1):

This is a basic answer to how you can parallelize your computations. Note Thymen's comment explaining that this answer is limited to the usage of 1 core. So if you can run 4 threads on your core, you'll potentially go 4 times faster (surely less in reality).

```py
import threading

results = []

# 1. create & start the first 4 threads (one per point value)
test_threads = []
def point_task(points):
    # you have to do this computation once before you can run your 3 test threads
    df_dx, db_dy = simulate_cointegration(num_points=points, stax=0.0100, stay=0.0050, coex=0.0200, coey=0.0200)

    # each thread will do some computation & appends the results
    thread1 = threading.Thread(target=lambda dx, dy: results.append(johansen_test(dx, dy)), args=(df_dx, db_dy))
    thread2 = threading.Thread(target=lambda dx, dy: results.append(cadf_test(dx, dy)), args=(df_dx, db_dy))
    thread3 = threading.Thread(target=lambda dx, dy: results.append(po_test(dx, dy)), args=(df_dx, db_dy))

    # remember the three tasks to call thread.join() at the end
    test_threads.append(thread1)
    test_threads.append(thread2)
    test_threads.append(thread3)

    # then start all the tasks while you prepare the others
    thread1.start()
    thread2.start()
    thread3.start()

# 2. create one thread per point value, each thread will create three new threads
points_threads = []
for points in [250, 500, 1000, 4000]:
    thread = threading.Thread(target=point_task, args=(points,))
    points_threads.append(thread)

# 3. start all the threads
for thread in points_threads:
    thread.start()

# 4. make sure the first four threads are finished before making sure the test_threads are over as well
#    this is because if one of the first threads is no over yet, then you might have a missing thread in 'tests_threads' on which you won't be able to call '.join()'
for thread in points_threads:
    thread.join()
for thread in tests_threads:
    thread.join()

print(results)
```

So if use a simple implementation of the other methods :

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

def simulate_cointegration(num_points=100, stax=0.0100, stay=0.0050, coex=0.0200, coey=0.0200):
    return 1, 1

def johansen_test(dx, dy):
    return 1

def cadf_test(dx, dy):
    return 2

def po_test(dx, dy):
    return 3
```

Then you get the following results:

```py
print(results)
>>> [1, 2, 1, 3, 1, 2, 1, 3, 2, 3, 2, 3]
```

If you wish to use more cores, see [multiprocessing](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html) or [MPI](https://bitbucket.org/mpi4py/mpi4py/).

Also, I am not sure how Python manages the critical resources, but you might want to use [locks](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#threading.Lock.acquire) on your results list or replace it with [queues](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#threading.Lock.acquire) for good practice.

Edit : just found this answer [Are lists thread-safe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6319207/are-lists-thread-safe). So you should be able to keep your list as a simple python list, as long as you keep to the `threading` module and do not use `multiprocessing` or something else.