# Writing an append only dict to disk avoiding thread locking

Tags: python, multithreading, dictionary, iteration, locking

I have a dict which has 20,000 keys and total size of dict is 150MB. I dump the dict via pickle to disk every hour and then load the pickle file on program startup.
Here is the gist of the writing code

```
cache_copy = copy.deepcopy(self.cache) 
#self.cache is the dict
pickle.dump(cache_copy, cache_file, pickle.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL)
```

Sometimes I get the following error

```
cache_copy = copy.deepcopy(self.cache)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/copy.py", line 163, in deepcopy
y = copier(x, memo)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/copy.py", line 256, in _deepcopy_dict
for key, value in x.iteritems():
RuntimeError: dictionary changed size during iteration
```

What is the best way to do this? I want to really avoid thread locking as it makes code complex. If it is really necessary, locking should be as minimal/simple as possible and allow for some concurrency. There are several constraints in my code that could help in this direction:

- Multiples threads read and write to the dict(). However, in all writes only (key,value) pairs are added. (key, value) pairs are never deleted or modified
- I am open to changing the data structure from dict() to something else. It should have functionality of fast memory lookup and writes
- I don't mind stale writes. So if the dict() had some appends, and we write to a dict snapshot that is few seconds older that is ok.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## TL;DR edit

To avoid locking the dict during pickling, create a list that duplicates the dict:

```
# When you do this:
cache["new_key"] = "new_value"
# Also do this:
cache_list.append(("new_key", "new_value"))
```

And pickle the list instead.

Preferably, append to `cache_file` instead of overwriting it. This way, you can `cache_list.clear()` after each write to file, avoiding waste of memory and disk writes. But there can be a bug when some thread writes to the list right after the pickling, and then that value gets `clear`ed. Maybe you're OK with losing some values if this is just a cache. If not, use some locks or just don't `clear` the list. I was incorrect about double memory usage because the list doesn't `deepcopy` the data, it only stores 20000 tuples, each with 2 references.

## Original answer

You need to lock all writes if you want to iterate, copy or pickle your dict. However, if you *really* don't want to lock the threads that use the dict and you don't mind doubling your memory usage, I can suggest keeping a list of key-value pairs (which duplicates your dict), a lock for that list and a queue of writes to that list:

```
# When you do this:
cache["new_key"] = "new_value"

# Also do this:
if not list_is_locked:
    cache_list.append(("new_key", "new_value"))
else:
    # Write here immediately instead of waiting for list to unlock
    queue.append(("new_key", "new_value"))
```

And when the pickling time comes, you lock and pickle that list instead of the dict:

```
list_is_locked = True
# pickle cache_list here
list_is_locked = False
cache_list.extend(queue)
queue.clear()
```

I'm not really familiar with `pickle`, but if it's possible to append to `cache_file` instead of overwriting it, you could also clear the list after pickling it. That would help to avoid that huge memory burden.

Comment: Very elegant answer. Can the list lock also be removed https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6319207/are-lists-thread-safe as we are ok with stale writes

Comment: The lock was intended to protect the iterator during pickling. I was expecting that it would throw the same `"changed size during iteration"` error as dict iterator. But I've actually tried to invalidate a list iterator right now, and it doesn't throw. So yes, you don't need neither a lock nor a queue, only a list. I'll edit my answer