# written a thread unsafe code but acting as thread safe why?

Tags: python-3.x, thread-safety, python-multiprocessing, python-multithreading

i watched this video and written this code in python https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oYoVx8ZuvTw
but my code is acting as thread safe why
please see video to understand my query

```
import threading
import random

class ConcurrentQueue:
    def __init__(self):
        self.queue = []

    def enqueue(self, item):
        self.queue.append(item)

    def size(self):
        return len(self.queue)

NUM_THREADS = 1000000

def main():
    queue = ConcurrentQueue()

    def enqueue_task():
        queue.enqueue(random.randint(1, 1000000))

    # Create and start enqueue threads
    enqueue_threads = [threading.Thread(target=enqueue_task) for _ in range(NUM_THREADS)]
    for thread in enqueue_threads:
        thread.start()

    # Wait for enqueue threads to finish
    for thread in enqueue_threads:
        thread.join()

    print("size:", queue.size())

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

i an expecting a size less than 1000000 but giving 1000000

Comment: Appending to a list is thread safe. See also https://docs.python.org/3/faq/library.html#what-kinds-of-global-value-mutation-are-thread-safe

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Are lists thread-safe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6319207/are-lists-thread-safe)