# How to do a random sample without k, up until a certain integer is produced? (Python)

Tags: python, loops, while-loop, random

I'm working in Python, and basically I have a list of integers:

```
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 7, 7, 7, 7, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 9, 9, 9, 9, 10]
```

with the variable `total`, and I'm trying to figure out how to produce random numbers from this list (without replacement) until the 10 is produced, and then stop. I'm thinking that this would use `random.shuffle` within a while loop, but I'm not sure. Any tips or advice?

Comment: Sorry, what is the role of `total` in this scenario? You want to figure out how many loops it takes to produce `10`?

Comment: Yes, total is just my set of integers, which have varying numbers of 1, 2, 3...10, and I want to pull numbers randomly out of this set of integers until I get the 10, and then stop.

Comment: standard library ``random.choice`` *Choose a random element from a non-empty sequence.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `random.shuffle` doesn't even require a loop.

```
random.shuffle(l)
random_selection = l[ :l.index(10) ]
```

Comment: Thank you! I think this is what I'm looking for. However, it looks like it produces everything up to 10, but not including the 10. Is there anyway for it to include the 10?

Comment: @user2057725: `l.index(10) + 1`?

Answer (score 2):

You pop() a random element from `total` and then check if it's a `10`. For example:

```
while total.pop(random.randrange(len(total))) != 10:
     ... # do your stuff until the 10 is chosen
```

total.pop(i) removes from `total` the element of index `i`, so this will work **without replacement**. Also, [check out this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10048069/what-is-the-most-pythonic-way-to-pop-a-random-element-from-a-list).

**EDIT:**
Maybe what you're trying to achieve by having multiple times the same element is a weighted random selection; that would be a rather ugly solution. That being the case, see if this question (**[Weighted random selection with and without replacement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/352670/weighted-random-selection-with-and-without-replacement?rq=1)**) helps. Cheers.