# How to randomly select a tuple from a list?

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, random

I'm randomly creating a list of tuples from two tuples, like so:

```
tuple1 = ('green','yellow','blue','orange','indigo','violet')
tuple2 = ('tree',2,'horse',4,6,1,'banana')

mylist = [(t1,t2) for item1 in tuple1 for item2 in tuple2]
```

which of course gives me something like:

`[('green','tree'),('yellow', 2)]` and so on.

But then, I want to *randomly* select one two-item tuple from the generated `mylist`. In other words, return something like `('green',2)`.

How do I randomly select one two-item tuple from a list of them? I tried the following, but it isn't working:

```
my_single_tuple = random.choice(mylist.pop())
```

I'd be grateful for any clues or suggestions.

[EDIT] I wasn't clear about the goal: I want to **remove** (pop) the randomly selected tuple from the list.

Comment: the result of executing the above code: `NameError: name 't1' is not defined`

Comment: `random.choice` takes a list, so why not just `my_single_tuple = random.choice(mylist)`?

Comment: This should probably be `mylist = [(item1,item2) for item1 in tuple1 for item2 in tuple2]`

Comment: BTW, that `mylist` can be built with `mylist = list(zip(tuple1, tuple2))`

Comment: I made a slight edit to clarify: I want to remove the selected tuple, not just get it.

Comment: Then randomly choose a valid index and `.pop` it. The fact that it's a tuple at that index is irrelevant.

Comment: Once you have the combined list of tuples, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10048069/what-is-the-most-pythonic-way-to-pop-a-random-element-from-a-list to pop a random element

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to select a tuple and then remove it just get the index and remove it afterwards.

```
import random

tuple1 = ('green','yellow','blue','orange','indigo','violet')
tuple2 = ('tree',2,'horse',4,6,1,'banana')

mylist = [(item1,item2) for item1 in tuple1 for item2 in tuple2]


while len(mylist) > 0:
    index = random.randint(0,len(mylist)-1)
    print(mylist[index])
    del mylist[index]
```

Comment: I said, *"that's why there's literally a `random.randrange`"*. I'm not sure what that last change was in aid of either, was there some problem with `list.pop`? Some indication that the OP wanted to clear out the list entirely and only ever print the elements in it?

Comment: Why not use random.shuffle *once* then just pop elements from the end?

Answer (score 2):

If you need to do this multiple times, just shuffle the list once and then pop items from the front:

```
random.shuffle(mylist)
mylist.pop()
mylist.pop()
```

etc.

Comment: This is only valid if the original order of the list isn't useful.

Comment: Yes, I was thinking of the scenario where he'd pop random items from the list until the list was empty or some condition was met.

Answer (score 2):

I think I found an answer that works:

```
my_item = mylist.pop(random.randrange(len(mylist)))
```

This successfully gives me a random tuple from the list. Thanks @philipp-braun, your answer was very close, but didn't work for me.