# How to randomly discard a number of elements in a set using Python?

Tags: python, data-structures, set

for example, I have this Set object:

`a = {0,1,2,3,4,5}`

how to randomly remove fixed number of elements from this set?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the most pythonic way to pop a random element from a list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10048069/what-is-the-most-pythonic-way-to-pop-a-random-element-from-a-list)

Comment: @Vallentin: The questions are quite different - just list vs set is a huge difference.

Comment: How "random" does it need to be?

Comment: @StefanPochmann it does not need to be cryptographically random, in my use case. but you're right, it might be a legit concern for someone.

Comment: But still "random", I guess, not just "arbitrary"? Just asking because of `for _ in range(2): a.pop()`.

Comment: yeah , probably not like that. :P

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To remove 2 random elements, sample 2 random elements, then remove them:

```
a.difference(random.sample(a, 2))
```

or just sample two elements less than the size of the set:

```
set(random.sample(a, len(a) - 2))
```

If you want a destructive operation (so that `a` changes), you can use `difference_update` on it instead:

```
a.difference_update(random.sample(a, 2))
```

Comment: I wish `set(random.sample(a, -2))` would do what I'd obviously like it to do :-)

Answer (score 0):

A possible approach is to choose the number of elements to remove, iterate over the later range, and choose a value to remove:

```
import random
a = {0,1,2,3,4,5}
n = 2
for i in range(n):
   val = random.choice(list(a))
   a.remove(val)
```

Or, even shorter, a comprehension:

```
vals = [random.choice(list(a)) for i in range(n)]
a = {i for i in a if i not in vals}
```

Comment: Both are very inefficient, and the second one is wrong.