# How to pop out multiple random elements from a list in Python?

Tags: python

I am trying to delete elements from original list whenever I sample from it.

```
list_a = ["a", "b", "c", "d"]
list_b = np.random.choice(list_a, 2)
```

When I `np.random.choice`, I want `list_a` to be a list without the elements of `list_b`.

Comment: Check this out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10048069/what-is-the-most-pythonic-way-to-pop-a-random-element-from-a-list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can shuffle the list and then split it, giving you the sampled elements and the remaining elements.

```
import numpy as np
list_a = ["a", "b", "c", "d"]
np.random.shuffle(list_a)
list_b, list_a = list_a[:2], list_a[2:]
```

Answer (score 0):

You could have a list excluded the elements of `list_a` that exist in `list_b`:

Using list comprehension:

```
list_a = ["a", "b", "c", "d"]
list_b = np.random.choice(list_a, 2)

print([x for x in list_a if x not in list_b])
print(list_b)
```

**OUTPUT**:

```
['c', 'd']
['b' 'a']
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be done using the remove() python has.

You can read more about the remove() here: https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/list/remove

```
import numpy as np
list_a = ["a", "b", "c", "d"]
list_b = np.random.choice(list_a, 2)

for i in list_b:
    list_a.remove(i)

print list_a
print list_b
```

RESULTS:

```
list_a = [a, c]
list_b = [b, d]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> list_a = ["a", "b", "c", "d"]
>>> _ = [list_a.remove(i) for i in np.random.choice(list_a, 2) if i in list_a]
>>> list_a
['b', 'd']
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Answer (score 0):

Rather then using the `choice` function you can get a random integer as index and use `pop()` on the list:

```py
import random

list_a = ["a", "b", "c", "d"]
def select_and_remove(list, items):
    sample = []
    for i in range(0, items)
        sample.append(list.pop(random.randint(0, len(list)-1))
    return list, sample
```

Then run:

```py
list_a, sample = select_and_remove(list_a, 2)
```

Note however, this will throw a `ValueError` if the list is empty or if you want to select more items as available