# How to replace the specified dash with the letter

Tags: python, character-replacement

I wish to write a hangman program and in order to do so, I have to replace the hash ('-') letter(s) with the user's guessed letter (`guess`). But when I run the code, it replaces all the hashes with the user's guess letter.
The code seems okay but I don't get the desired result.

- `words` is a list of words I have written before the function.

```py
def word_guess():
    random.shuffle(words)
    word = words[0]
    words.pop(0)

    print(word)
    l_count = 0
    for letter in word:
        l_count += 1

    # the hidden words are shown a '-'
    blank = '-' * l_count
    print(blank)

    guess = input("please guess a letter  ")

    if guess in word:
        # a list of the position of all the specified letters in the word
        a = [i for i, letter in enumerate(word) if letter == guess]

        for num in a:
            blank_reformed = blank.replace(blank[num], guess)
            print(blank_reformed)


word_guess()
```

e.g: when the `word` is 'funny', and `guess` is 'n', the output is 'nnnnn'.

How should I replace the desired hash string with `guess` letter?

Comment: I would go in the opposite direction. Keep track of correctly guessed letters, and display `''.join([x if x in correct_guesses else '-' for x in word])`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> it replaces all the hashes

[This is exactly what `blank.replace` is supposed to do](https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/stdtypes.html#str.replace), though.

What you should do is replace *that single character* of the string. Since strings are immutable, you can't really do this. However, *lists* of strings are mutable, so you could do `blank = ['-'] * l_count`, which would be a list of dashes, and then modify `blank[num]`:

```
for num in a:
   blank[num] = guess
   print(blank)
```

Answer (score 0):

A couple things to note:

- inefficient/un-pythonic `pop` operation (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10048069/what-is-the-most-pythonic-way-to-pop-a-random-element-from-a-list))
- `l_count` is just `len(word)`
- un-pythonic, unreadable replacement

Instead, here's a better implementation:

```py
def word_guess() -> str:
    random.shuffle(words)
    word = words.pop()
    
    guess = input()

    out = ''
    for char in word:
        if char == guess:
            out.append(char)
        else:
            out.append('-')
    return out
```

Comment: Thanks. And you probably should realize and take note that string objects have no attribute called 'append'

Answer (score 0):

If you don't plan to use the locations of the correct guess later on, then you can simplify the last section of code:

```
word = 'hangman'
blank = '-------'
guess = 'a'

if guess in word:
    blank_reformed = ''.join(guess if word[i] == guess else blank[i] for i in range(len(word)))
    
blank_reformed
'-a---a-'
```

(You still have some work to do make the overall game work...)