# Select a variable in a collection based on avoiding another

Tags: python, logic

I have a collection of two variables

```
a = 2
b = 3
collection = [a, b]
```

I randomly choose one of them as my first variable:

```
first_variable = random.choice(collection)
```

Later, I want to select the other variable and store it in `other_variable`.
How can I do this only by referring to `first_variable` and `collection`?

other_variable = something like "variable in `collection` that is not `first_variable`"

Remark: The collection will always contain two elements only.
Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Straight-forward:

```
a = 2
b = 3
collection = [a, b]

import random

first_variable = random.choice(collection)
other_variable = [item for item in collection if item != first_variable][0]

print(other_variable)
```

Caution: this will obviously fail if `a == b` (it will produce an `IndexError`).

Comment: Thank you. Why did you specify the [0] in the end?

Comment: @lonyen11: Because this is a list comprehension and you'll get a list with only one element.

Comment: You might also consider this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10048069/what-is-the-most-pythonic-way-to-pop-a-random-element-from-a-list

Comment: A list comprehension is overkill. Just use a ternary with a 2-element list: `other = collection[0] if collection[0] != first else collection[1]`

Comment: @Woodford: You're absolutely right. However, list comprehensions are really fast in `Python`.

Answer (score 0):

Just `shuffle` your collection and use the indexes to refer to your `first` and `other` variables:

```py
>>> import random
>>> collection = [2, 3]
>>> random.shuffle(collection)
>>> print(f'first={collection[0]}, other={collection[1]}')
first=3, other=2
```