# How can I fix an IndexError regarding the random choice method?

Tags: python, random

I am getting an `IndexError` and I'm unsure why.

```
cards = [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 ,11, 12, 13, 14,
         2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14,
         2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14,
         2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14]
USER = []
CPU = []
selected = 1
while selected < 26:
    CPU.append(cards.pop(random.choice(cards)))
    USER.append(cards.pop(random.choice(cards)))
    selected = selected + 1
```

I want the items inside the list `cards` to be appended into the lists `USER` and `CPU`. It worked originally but after working on something else it stopped working. I looked up why but the `pop` index says it's out of range, but I don't understand why.

Comment: Please update your question with the full error traceback.

Comment: The first argument passed to list pop method must be a valid *index* of the list, not the value of some element in the list (per the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#mutable-sequence-types)).

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that `random.choice()` returns a random value from the list, but the argument to `cards.pop()` must be an index. When the list becomes shorter than 14 elements, some of the values will be invalid indexes and you'll get an error.

A simpler way to do this is to just shuffle the `cards` list and then assign half to each player.

```
random.shuffle(cards)
CPU = cards[:26]
USER = cards[26:]
```

Comment: @Solidpanda2191: Also note that this code, besides being way faster than the way you're trying to do things, also happens to be very similar to the way real cards would be manipulated to achieve the same goal.

Answer (score 0):

I'd change the while line into: `while not cards`. If cards is an empty list, this returns false and exits the loop. Please keep in mind that since You're taking more than one card out of the list, this may fail if 52/(takings per iteration) gives a non-0 remainder.

Comment: That won't fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Since `random.choice(cards)` returns a value from the list `cards`, that means that if you pass the result into `cards.pop()`, which expects you to pass in the *index* of an item, that means that you could potentially pass an index into the `pop()` which is out of range. For instance, if your list `cards` has a length of `9` at some point while you're running your script, and `random.choice(cards)` happens to return `11`, then you'll get an error about the pop index.

The solution for how to pop a random item out of a list has already been covered here so I'm not going to repeat it in this answer. [What is the most pythonic way to pop a random element from a list?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10048069/6273251)

Answer (score 0):

As I mention in a comment, the `IndexError` is because you're passing and element of the list instead of its index to the `pop()` method. One way to avoid the problem would be to instead use [`random.randrange()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.randrange) to pick a valid value to pass it:

```
import random

cards = [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 ,11, 12, 13, 14,
         2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14,
         2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14,
         2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14]
USER = []
CPU = []
selected = 1
while selected < 26:
    CPU.append(cards.pop(random.randrange(len(cards))))
    USER.append(cards.pop(random.randrange(len(cards))))
    selected += 1
```