# subprocess.check_output with grep command fails when grep finds no matches

Tags: python, grep, subprocess

I'm trying to search a text file and retrieve lines containing a specific set of words. This is the code I'm using:

```
tyrs = subprocess.check_output('grep "^A" %s | grep TYR' % pocket_location, shell = True).split('\n')
```

This works fine when the file contains at least one line that grep identifies. But when grep doesn't identify any lines, grep returns exit status 1 and I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "../../Python_scripts/cbs_wrapper2.py", line 324, in <module>
    tyrs = subprocess.check_output('grep "^ATOM" %s | grep TYR' % pocket_location, shell = True).split('\n')
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 544, in check_output
    raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd, output=output)
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command 'grep "^ATOM" cbsPrediction_files/1u9c_clean/1u9c_clean_fpocket_out/pockets/pocket0_atm.pdb | grep TYR' returned non-zero exit status 1
```

How can I avoid this issue? I just want `subprocess.check_output` to return an empty string if grep doesn't find anything.

Thanks

Comment: use `pipes.quote(pocket_location)` to allow the path with characters that are special in a shell such as space character.

Answer (score 14):

> I just want subprocess.check_output to return an empty string if grep doesn't find anything.

Well, too bad. [`grep`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/grep.html) considers no matches to be failure, and the whole point of the `check` in [`check_output`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_output) is to check for failure, so you're explicitly asking to do things this way. Here are the relevant docs:

> If the return code was non-zero it raises a CalledProcessError. The CalledProcessError object will have the return code in the returncode attribute and any output in the output attribute.

And for `grep`:

```
The following exit values shall be returned:
  0 One or more lines were selected.
  1 No lines were selected.
  >1 An error occurred.
```

So, if you want to treat "no lines" as success, but actual errors as errors, you have to handle that `1` value differently than other non-zero values. And `check_output` has no idea that you want to do that.

So, either you have to handle the `CalledProcessError`, or you have to do your own checking. In other words, either this:

```
try:
    tyrs = subprocess.check_output('grep "^A" %s | grep TYR' % pocket_location, shell = True).split('\n')
except subprocess.CalledProcessError as e:
    if e.returncode > 1:
        raise
    tyrs = []
```

… or this:

```
p = subprocess.Popen('grep "^A" %s | grep TYR' % pocket_location, shell=True,
                     stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
output, _ = p.communicate()
if p.returncode == 1: # no matches found 
    tyrs = []
elif p.returncode == 0: # matches found
    tyrs = output.split('\n')
else:
    # error, do something with it
```

Answer (score 6):

```
tyrs = subprocess.check_output('grep "^A" %s | grep TYR || true' % pocket_location, shell = True).split('\n')
```

Comment: The shell command is ended with call to true which ensures the return code is always 0

Comment: Of course, if the grep fails for any other reason you are screwed with this approach. I suggest to take the abarnert solution if you are serious about programming.

Answer (score 0):

For future reference, if anyone is looking for a similar solution using `pgrep` -

```
import subprocess    
var = subprocess.check_output("pgrep -af 'python3 choice_multi.py CMC0001'", shell=True, text=True)
var = var.splitlines()
var = [x for x in var if '/bin/sh' not in x]
print(var )
```

This will come as an irritating error if you do `pgrep` because it also shows the `PID` of the temporary process being created.

Now the `/bin/sh` can be different for other systems.
Alternatively, there are two other solutions that I thought as inefficient -

1. You can just delete the first item in the list.
2. You can check the length of the list and scan for the above 1 only because all of them will have a minimum 1 `PID`.

References -
[Is there a simple way to delete a list element by value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2793324/is-there-a-simple-way-to-delete-a-list-element-by-value)