# Getting rid of 'nan' from list value of dictionary , python

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, dictionary

I have this dictionary:

```
dict_new = 
{'extracted_layout': [nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, 'shyamanna layout', nan, nan, nan, nan, 'm t s layout', nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, 'green glen layout', nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, 'h s r layout', nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, 'vikas layout', 'annaiah reddy layout', nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, 'andhra muniyappa layout', nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, 'lake city layout', nan, 'h s r layout'}
```

It has one key, `extracted_layout`  and its values are in a list that is stuffed with nans . How do I get rid of them?

Comment: please explain the reason for a downvote , is my question a duplicate ? or not specific?

Comment: That doesn't make any sense ?? JUst downvote because the question is too small , really sad..

Comment: your comment is just an assumption ("because the question is too small") and probably not correct. The downvotes aren't from me but your question doesn't show any research effort. It doesn't say what you have tried so far. Thus your question is basically, "please do this for me". That's not liked by many.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a simple way to delete a list element by value in python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2793324/is-there-a-simple-way-to-delete-a-list-element-by-value-in-python)

Comment: It would be better if you specify the expected output, and what `nan`s are.

Comment: The reason for downvote is probably due to lack of reason for question, what do you want to do this for? What is your required/expected output? What have you tried? Why didn't that work?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If `nan` is float nan, use [`math.isnan`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/math.html#math.isnan) to filter it out:

```
>>> import math
>>> nan = float('nan')
>>> nan
nan
>>> math.isnan(nan)
True
>>> math.isnan(1)
False
```

---

```
import math

dict_new['extracted_layout'] = [
    x
    for x in dict_new['extracted_layout']
    if not (isinstance(x, float) and math.isnan(x))
]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
list_dict = [{"year": 1916, "age": 10},
        {"year": 1826, "age": 'NaN'},
        {"year": 'NaN', "age": 7}]
for my_dict in list_dict:
    for k in my_dict:
        if isnan(float(my_dict[k])):
            my_dict[k] = 0
```