# How to remove something from a list that is made from user input python

Tags: python, list, input

So I am coding a checklist in Python 3.5.2. Part of my checklist is the function that is removing something in the list by typing the name of the thing in the list. I have been trying to figure out a way to do it but have not found one. 
Here is the code that I am working with:

```
import time
import random 
#Intro tells player how to use program
def displayIntro():
    print("Hello there, welcome to your Python Checklist.")
    time.sleep(2)
    print("Please type the name of the chore e.g. rubbish.")
    time.sleep(2)
    print("To remove a completed chore, type ‘done’ then the name of the chore e.g. done rubbish.")
    time.sleep(3)
    print("It will tick the box next to the chore you said. ☑")
    time.sleep(2)
    print("To show unfinished chores type ‘display’ with check boxes next to them. ☐")

#Stores user input in a list
def nameChores():
    chores = ''
    chores2 = ()
    chores3 = ''
    chores2 = input('Type chore name: ').split()
    print("Chore(s) is now stored.")
    while chores != 'display' and chores in chores2:
        time.sleep(0.5)
        print('Make sure to look at the intro for the commands.')
        chores = input().lower()

#Displays the unfinished chores that the player has typed in and appear with unfilled checkboxes next to them
    if chores == 'display':
        print(chores2)
    return chores

#Program looks for chore name and removes it from the list. Says to player it is removed with a tick next to it. 
    if chores in chores2: 
        chores2.remove(chores)
        print("Chore is now remove. ☑")




nameChores()
```

Comment: Is this what you want? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2793324/is-there-a-simple-way-to-delete-a-list-element-by-value-in-python

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import time

currentChores = []
finishedChores = []

def displayIntro():
    print("Hello there, welcome to your Python Checklist.")
    time.sleep(2)
    print("Please type the name of the chore e.g. rubbish.")
    time.sleep(2)
    print("To remove a completed chore, type ‘done’ then the name of the chore e.g. done rubbish.")
    time.sleep(3)
    print("It will tick the box next to the chore you said. ☑")
    time.sleep(2)
    print("To show unfinished chores type ‘display’ with check boxes next to them. ☐")

def nameChores():
    chore = input("Type chore name: ")

    if (chore == "display"):
        print(currentChores)

    elif ("done " in chore):
        subString = chore.replace("done ", "")
        if subString in currentChores:
            currentChores.remove(subString)
            finishedChores.append(subString)
            print("Chore: " + subString + " was removed from your chore list")
        else:
            print("The chore: " + subString + " doesn't exist in your chore list")

    elif (chore not in currentChores):
        currentChores.append(chore)
        print("Chore: " + chore + " was added to your chore list")






def main():

    nameChores()
main()
```

This code snippet will execute the `displayChores` intro, and then proceed to *continuously* add chores to the `currentChores` list by having the `nameChores`function in a infinite loop

If a `chore` is added twice, the `chore` will be removed from the `currentChores` list and added to the `finishedChores` list, where you easily can access all finished `chores`

You can easily make the script stop whenever you want by modifying the `nameChores` function:

```
def nameChores():
    while True:
        chore = input("Type chore name: ")

        if (chore == "display"):
            print(currentChores)

        elif (chore == "stop"):
            break

        elif ("done " in chore):
            subString = chore.replace("done ", "")
            if subString in currentChores:
                currentChores.remove(subString)
                finishedChores.append(subString)
                print("Chore: " + subString + " was removed from your chore list")
            else:
                print("The chore: " + subString + " doesn't exist in your chore list")

        elif (chore not in currentChores):
            currentChores.append(chore)
            print("Chore: " + chore + " was added to your chore list")
```