# How to remove Specific values in python list

Tags: python

```
result = [(u'ABC', u'(Choose field)', u'ABCD', u'aa', u'A', u'A_100')]
```

I'm trying to remove `'(Choose field)'` from the above list using the following syntax:

```
result.remove('(Choose field)')
# and  
result.remove("'(Choose field)'")
```

But both things are not working fine and it ends up with this error

```
{ValueError}list.remove(x): x not in list
```

Comment: Your list doesn't contain strings. It contains one tuple, which contains strings. However you're populating it, you're doing it wrong.

Comment: So may i have to work in How to remove tuple ?

Comment: If you want this to work, your result list should look like this: `result = [u'ABC', u'(Choose field)', u'ABCD', u'aa', u'A', u'A_100']`. Your list has only one tuple of strings and not different elements of strings.

Comment: You could convert it, e.g. `result = list(result[0])` . Or you could fix whatever's populating the list to do it correctly.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a simple way to delete a list element by value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2793324/is-there-a-simple-way-to-delete-a-list-element-by-value)

Comment: @sonuchauhan a duplicate of the question title, but it won't solve the issue in this question

Comment: Mr @sonuchauhan Well  Title  are same but Type and stuff is totally Different

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First of all, your list contains tuple which contains string. And tuple doesn't support `remove` Just convert tuples as list and then use `remove`

```
>>> res = list(result[0])
['ABC', '(Choose field)', 'ABCD', 'aa', 'A', 'A_100']
>>> res.remove('(Choose field)')
['ABC', 'ABCD', 'aa', 'A', 'A_100']
```

Answer (score 1):

You can convert the tuple inside the list to another list and remove the item from there. This should do the work:-

```
result = list(result[0])
result.remove(u'(Choose field)')
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use *indexing* and specifically want to remove `'a'` and `'b'` from **distinct** list: `values = ['a', 1, 2, 3, 'b']` - you can do this:

```
pop_list=['a','b']
[values.pop(values.index(p))  for p in pop_list if p in values]
```

above will remove `'a'` and `'b'` *in place* - **to get**:

```
print(values)   

[1, 2, 3]
```