# How to delete a list within a list?

Tags: python, list

I am trying to delete a list within a list but my code is unable to do so even though I have deleted the list.

```
y = [45]  
x = [1,2,3,5,y]    

del y        
print(x)
```

Output of printing x:

```
[1, 2, 3, 5, [45]]
```

My output shows as `[1, 2, 3, 5, [45]]` which means list `y` still exists in list `x`.
But I deleted list `y` in my code. Why is list `y` still not deleted then? Is there something wrong with my code? How do I delete an entire list in Python?

Comment: `del` deletes references, not objects. In your case you have to use the `.remove()` method of the list `x` and remove all other references to the list, then the list will eventually be garbage collected.

Comment: When `y` is put into `x`, the value of `y` is retrieved, not a weak reference. This means that though they are the same list, deleting `y` will not remove it from all the places it's used in. If you want, check out the `weakref` module. If you wanted to clear the list, use `list.clear`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a simple way to delete a list element by value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2793324/is-there-a-simple-way-to-delete-a-list-element-by-value)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look [here](http://pythontutor.com/composingprograms.html#code=y%20%3D%20%5B45%5D%20%20%0Ax%20%3D%20%5B1,2,3,5,y%5D%20%20%20%20%0A%0Adel%20y%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%0Aprint%28x%29&cumulative=false&curInstr=0&mode=display&origin=composingprograms.js&py=3&rawInputLstJSON=%5B%5D) and have a play with it.

In python, all `variables` are just `names`, which are bound to objects. It is not same as `C` or `C++`, where `variables` are `memory locations`.

In your code, `y` and `x[4]` are both bound to `[45]`, which is a list object. When you `del y`, you can not stop `x[4]` from being bound to `[45]`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove `n`-th element of `list`, you should use `del` following way:

```
y = [45]
x = [1,2,3,5,y]
del x[4] # 4 means last element of x as indexing starts with 0
print(x) # [1,2,3,5]
print(y) # [45]
```

Note that after that `y` remains unaltered. `list`s have also method `.remove` which will remove first occurence, consider following example:

```
a = [1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3]
a.remove(3)
print(a) # [1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3]
```

`remove` will cause `ValueError` if there is not element in `list`.

Answer (score 0):

Delete a list which is present inside the another list.

By using remove function,we can also delete a list which is present Inside the other.

Run the Following code:

```
y = [45]  
x = [1,2,3,5,y]    

x.remove(y)
print(x)
```

`x.remove(y)` which removes the y list in the x list.

output:

[1, 2, 3, 5]