# How can I remove an object from array in python?

Tags: python, arrays

How can I remove an object from array in python?

I want to select an msgID and want to delete that full object with username, msg, time_stamp (all of it).

```
room_msg =  [
 {
  'msgID': 1, 
  'username': 'User1',
  'msg': 'msg1', 
  'time_stamp': 'May-31 05:29PM'},
 {
  'msgID': 2,
  'username': 'User2', 
  'msg': 'msg2', 
  'time_stamp': 'May-31 05:29PM'},
{
  'msgID': 3, 
  'username': 'User3', 
  'msg': 'msg3', 
  'time_stamp': 'May-31 05:29PM'} ]
```

Like if I select `'msgID': 3` 
after deleting the `'msgID': 3` the array should like this

```
room_msg = [
 {
  'msgID': 1, 
  'username': 'User1',
  'msg': 'msg1', 
  'time_stamp': 'May-31 05:29PM'},
 {
  'msgID': 2,
  'username': 'User2', 
  'msg': 'msg2', 
  'time_stamp': 'May-31 05:29PM'}
]
```

Is that possible?
I can't find x with that msgID `room_msg[x]`.

Comment: FWIW: Python has lists as the basic sequence collection type, not arrays; [..] creates a list. There are many examples on how to manipulate lists - now using the right terminology, try some internet/SO searches. “python remove list item by property” (eg.)

Comment: any code you have tried to solve this problem.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a simple way to delete a list element by value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2793324/is-there-a-simple-way-to-delete-a-list-element-by-value)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This simple code should do it:

```
desired_id = 3  # example id

for i, msg in enumerate(room_msg):
    if msg['msgID'] == desired_id:
        del room_msg[i]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use list comprehension:

```
room_msg = [m for m in room_msg if m['msgID'] != 3]

from pprint import pprint
pprint(room_msg)
```

Prints:

```
[{'msg': 'msg1',
  'msgID': 1,
  'time_stamp': 'May-31 05:29PM',
  'username': 'User1'},
 {'msg': 'msg2',
  'msgID': 2,
  'time_stamp': 'May-31 05:29PM',
  'username': 'User2'}]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `del` on the matching array indices.

```
for index, msg in enumerate(room_msg):
    if msg['msgID'] == 3:
        del room_msg[index]
```

Answer (score 0):

This could be a way - or you use the msgID as Ident for nested - than you can erase with del room_msg[msg]

```
def search_and_delete(msg):
    count = 0
    for x in room_msg:
        if x['msgID'] == msg:
            room_msg.pop(count)
        count+=1
```

Answer (score 0):

To delete a object from an array in python use

```
del arr["index"]
```