# Removing the item from np.array() 1d

Tags: python, numpy

For example

From this array

`[1,1,2,3,1,2,-1,2,-1]`

I want to remove `-1`
then make
`[1,1,2,3,1,2,2]`

I found function `np.setdiff1d`, but it sorts the final result automatically.

I want to remove only `-1` and keep order of other item.

Is there any good idea?

Comment: `arr[arr != -1]`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a simple way to delete a list element by value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2793324/is-there-a-simple-way-to-delete-a-list-element-by-value)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`x[x!=-1]` would do the trick

```
x = np.array([1,1,2,3,1,2,-1,2,-1])

x = x[x!=-1]

print x
# [1 1 2 3 1 2 2]
```