# Why I can't remove some value in list?

Tags: python

```py
matched_edges = [(0, -1), (1, -1), (2, 3), (3, 2), (4, 6), (5, 7), (6, 4), (7, 5), (8, 9), (9, 8)]
process = matched_edges
print(process)

for tup in matched_edges:
    if (tup[1], tup[0]) in process:
        process.remove((tup[1], tup[0]))
    if -1 in tup:
        process.remove(tup)
        print(tup)
print(process)
```

> [(0, -1), (1, -1), (2, 3), (3, 2), (4, 6), (5, 7), (6, 4), (7, 5), (8, 9), (9, 8)]
> (0, -1)
> [(1, -1), (2, 3), (4, 6), (5, 7), (8, 9)]

I tried many ways, but I just can't remove (1,-1).What's wrong?

```py
-1 in (1, -1)
```

> True

Comment: What condition must be met for the tuple to be removed?

Comment: When -1 in the tuple or the same but different order tuples.Like (1,2) and (2,1), then I need to remove one of it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a simple way to delete a list element by value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2793324/is-there-a-simple-way-to-delete-a-list-element-by-value)

Comment: bear in mind that `process` and `matched_edges` are references to the same list, so you are [iterating](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1207406/how-to-remove-items-from-a-list-while-iterating) over a list whilst removing from it.

Comment: Given your explanation @NiceChang `when -1 in tuple or reversed tuple exists` it seems your entire list would be removed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just create a new list.

```
matched_edges = [(0, -1), (1, -1), (2, 3), (3, 2), (4, 6), (5, 7), (6, 4), (7, 5), (8, 9), (9, 8)]
process = []
for tup in matched_edges:
    if (tup[1], tup[0]) in matched_edges:matched_edges.remove((tup[1], tup[0]))
    if -1 not in tup:process.append(tup)
print(process)
```

**output**

```
[(2, 3), (4, 6), (5, 7), (8, 9)]
```

Answer (score 3):

This is the incorrect line

```
process = matched_edges
```

Here is a programming rule. As much as possible, do not update the object you are currently iterating on! What was done in your code is that process and matched_edges points/refers to the same object/list in heap memory (different stack variables but both pointing to the same memory address in heap which is the actual list) thus updating process means you are also indirectly updating matched_edges.

You are currently iterating matched_edges:

```
for tup in matched_edges:
```

Then, you updated process, which messed up your iteration of matched_edges:

```
process.remove(...)
```

The correction to your code is to use this instead:

```
process = matched_edges.copy()
```

Comment: Beat me to it :)

Answer (score 1):

This line `process = matched_edges` is actually creating a reference to the `matched_edges` list, not a copy of the items. In turn, this is affecting your iterator in the for loop as you remove items from `process` (and `matched_edges`). To demonstrate I slightly modified your code (just to print values):

```
matched_edges = [(0, -1), (1, -1), (2, 3), (3, 2), (4, 6), (5, 7), (6, 4), (7, 5), (8, 9), (9, 8)]
process = matched_edges

for tup in matched_edges:
    print(f"Current tup: {tup}")
    print(f"Process: {process}")
    print(f"Matched: {matched_edges}")
    if (tup[1], tup[0]) in process:
        process.remove((tup[1], tup[0]))
    if -1 in tup:
        process.remove(tup)
```

Output:

```
Current tup: (0, -1)
Process: [(0, -1), (1, -1), (2, 3), (3, 2), (4, 6), (5, 7), (6, 4), (7, 5), (8, 9), (9, 8)]
Matched: [(0, -1), (1, -1), (2, 3), (3, 2), (4, 6), (5, 7), (6, 4), (7, 5), (8, 9), (9, 8)]
Current tup: (2, 3)
Process: [(1, -1), (2, 3), (3, 2), (4, 6), (5, 7), (6, 4), (7, 5), (8, 9), (9, 8)]
Matched: [(1, -1), (2, 3), (3, 2), (4, 6), (5, 7), (6, 4), (7, 5), (8, 9), (9, 8)]
Current tup: (4, 6)
Process: [(1, -1), (2, 3), (4, 6), (5, 7), (6, 4), (7, 5), (8, 9), (9, 8)]
Matched: [(1, -1), (2, 3), (4, 6), (5, 7), (6, 4), (7, 5), (8, 9), (9, 8)]
Current tup: (5, 7)
Process: [(1, -1), (2, 3), (4, 6), (5, 7), (7, 5), (8, 9), (9, 8)]
Matched: [(1, -1), (2, 3), (4, 6), (5, 7), (7, 5), (8, 9), (9, 8)]
Current tup: (8, 9)
Process: [(1, -1), (2, 3), (4, 6), (5, 7), (8, 9), (9, 8)]
Matched: [(1, -1), (2, 3), (4, 6), (5, 7), (8, 9), (9, 8)]
```

You can see on the second iteration you end up skipping the `(1, -1)` tuple. In general, you're skipping an item every time you remove one.

Change your assignment to `process` to use `copy()` so you get a new list:

```
process = matched_edges.copy()
```

This should fix the odd behavior. Although I'm not quite sure if the loop you're using still does exactly what you intend it to, but this is the output with the copied list:

```
Current tup: (0, -1)
Process: [(0, -1), (1, -1), (2, 3), (3, 2), (4, 6), (5, 7), (6, 4), (7, 5), (8, 9), (9, 8)]
Matched: [(0, -1), (1, -1), (2, 3), (3, 2), (4, 6), (5, 7), (6, 4), (7, 5), (8, 9), (9, 8)]
Current tup: (1, -1)
Process: [(1, -1), (2, 3), (3, 2), (4, 6), (5, 7), (6, 4), (7, 5), (8, 9), (9, 8)]
Matched: [(0, -1), (1, -1), (2, 3), (3, 2), (4, 6), (5, 7), (6, 4), (7, 5), (8, 9), (9, 8)]
Current tup: (2, 3)
Process: [(2, 3), (3, 2), (4, 6), (5, 7), (6, 4), (7, 5), (8, 9), (9, 8)]
Matched: [(0, -1), (1, -1), (2, 3), (3, 2), (4, 6), (5, 7), (6, 4), (7, 5), (8, 9), (9, 8)]
Current tup: (3, 2)
Process: [(2, 3), (4, 6), (5, 7), (6, 4), (7, 5), (8, 9), (9, 8)]
Matched: [(0, -1), (1, -1), (2, 3), (3, 2), (4, 6), (5, 7), (6, 4), (7, 5), (8, 9), (9, 8)]
Current tup: (4, 6)
Process: [(4, 6), (5, 7), (6, 4), (7, 5), (8, 9), (9, 8)]
Matched: [(0, -1), (1, -1), (2, 3), (3, 2), (4, 6), (5, 7), (6, 4), (7, 5), (8, 9), (9, 8)]
Current tup: (5, 7)
Process: [(4, 6), (5, 7), (7, 5), (8, 9), (9, 8)]
Matched: [(0, -1), (1, -1), (2, 3), (3, 2), (4, 6), (5, 7), (6, 4), (7, 5), (8, 9), (9, 8)]
Current tup: (6, 4)
Process: [(4, 6), (5, 7), (8, 9), (9, 8)]
Matched: [(0, -1), (1, -1), (2, 3), (3, 2), (4, 6), (5, 7), (6, 4), (7, 5), (8, 9), (9, 8)]
Current tup: (7, 5)
Process: [(5, 7), (8, 9), (9, 8)]
Matched: [(0, -1), (1, -1), (2, 3), (3, 2), (4, 6), (5, 7), (6, 4), (7, 5), (8, 9), (9, 8)]
Current tup: (8, 9)
Process: [(8, 9), (9, 8)]
Matched: [(0, -1), (1, -1), (2, 3), (3, 2), (4, 6), (5, 7), (6, 4), (7, 5), (8, 9), (9, 8)]
Current tup: (9, 8)
Process: [(8, 9)]
Matched: [(0, -1), (1, -1), (2, 3), (3, 2), (4, 6), (5, 7), (6, 4), (7, 5), (8, 9), (9, 8)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried something like

```
process = [tup for tup in matched_edges if (tup[0] != -1 and tup[1] != -1)]
```

That should remove any tuple with -1 in it.

**Edit**

Also, the reason the code is behaving strangely is that matched_edges and process both hold the same object, so as you remove objects from `process` you are also removing them from `matched_edges` during iteration, resulting in unexpected bahaviour. Run the following code and you will see what I mean.

```
matched_edges = [(0, -1), (1, -1), (2, 3), (3, 2), (4, 6), (5, 7), (6, 4), (7, 5), (8, 9), (9, 8)]
process = matched_edges
print(process)

for tup in matched_edges:
    print(tup)
    print("Length of matched edges:", len(matched_edges))
    if (tup[1], tup[0]) in process:
        process.remove((tup[1], tup[0]))
    if -1 in tup:
        process.remove(tup)
        print("removing", tup)
print(process)

matched_edges = [tup for tup in matched_edges if (tup[0] != -1 and tup[1] != -1)]
print(matched_edges)
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you do `process = matched_edges`, you are creating a variable (`process`) that points to the same object as `matched_edges`, to create a new list with the same values you should do `process = matched_edges[:]` instead.

So your code would look like:

```
matched_edges = [(0, -1), (1, -1), (2, 3), (3, 2), (4, 6), (5, 7), (6, 4), (7, 5), (8, 9), (9, 8)]
process = matched_edges[:]
print(process)

for tup in matched_edges:
    if (tup[1], tup[0]) in process:
        process.remove((tup[1], tup[0]))
    if -1 in tup:
        process.remove(tup)
        print(tup)
print(process)
```

Answer (score 0):

The following works fine for me.

```
matched_edges = [(0, -1), (1, -1), (2, 3), (3, 2), (4, 6), 
                (5, 7), (6, 4), (7, 5), (8, 9), (9, 8)]

process = []

for tup in matched_edges:
    if (tup[0] != -1 and tup[1] != -1) and (tup[1], tup[0]) not in process:
        process.append(tup)
print(process)
```

Output

```
[(2, 3), (4, 6), (5, 7), (8, 9)]
```