# Python: Want to have something taken out of a list how do I do this in python 3?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Here is my code if that helps you answer the question

```
import random

Exlist = ['pl1', 'pl2']
Exvar = random.choice(Exlist)
print(Exvar)
Exlist = Exlist - list(Exvar)
```

I tried changing Exvar to a list

Comment: I recommend that you check [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html) to see all of the functions you can do with lists. Scan down the page to see if any of these functions look like they will do what you want.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a simple way to delete a list element by value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2793324/is-there-a-simple-way-to-delete-a-list-element-by-value)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use remove(). For example,

```
import random

Exlist = ['pl1', 'pl2']
Exvar = random.choice(Exlist)
print(Exvar)
Exlist.remove(Exvar)
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to remove something from a list you can either *remove()* or *pop()* or possibly reconstruct the list omitting the element that's not required

Answer (score 0):

You can use remove() to remove item by content example:

```
Exlist.remove(Exvar)
```

You can use pop() to remove the last item or pass the index as parameter to remove specific item example:

```
Exlist.pop()
Exlist.pop(index)
```

You can also use del keyword to remove item by index example:

```
del Exlist[index]
```